# Command to append line to a text file without opening an editor

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-editor, redirect

Assuming i have a line that i want to add to a file without opening an editor.

How could i append this line

```
alias list='ls -cl --group-directories-first'
```

to this file

```
config.fish
```

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You can append a *line* of text to a file by using the `>>` operator:

```
echo "hello world" >> my_file.txt
```

or in your case

```
echo "alias list='ls -cl --group-directories-first'" >> config.fish
```

Please take note of the [different types of quotes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20034/differences-between-doublequotes-singlequotes-and-backticks-on-comma).

Comment: I use echo myself, but be careful, if you only specify one `>` then the file will truncate, not append. for a safer command you can use sed: `sed -i '$a hello world' filename`

Comment: explanation: `-i` will update the file (otherwise it will just print the result to stdout), `$` is regex that will match the end of the file, and `a` appends the following text to filename.

Comment: `echo "hello world" >> my_file.txt` does not create a new last line with `HW`, but add it to the string of the last line.

Comment: What is `HW` @timo ?

Comment: Maybe "Hello World" @7wp :) It's `echo` that adds the line break (making it a line as opposed to just a bunch of characters). You can switch off the line break at the end with `-n`.

Comment: what if i want to take the output from a command, in my case ´pwd´ and append the output?

Comment: for example, i can do pwd >> login.conf but can't seem to make it work with sed

Comment: Worth noting that the command @invert suggested (i.e., `sed -i '$a hello world' filename`) doesn't work if the file is completely empty (e.g., if it was generated with the command `: > filename`).

Answer (score 9):

There's plenty of methods of appending to file without opening text editors, particularly via multiple available text processing utilities in Ubuntu. In general, anything that allows us to perform `open()` syscall with `O_APPEND` flag added, can be used to append to a file.

- GNU version of `dd` utility can append data to file with `conv=notrunc oflag=append`

  ```
  printf "\nalias list='ls -cl --group-directories-first'\n" | dd conv=notrunc oflag=append bs=1 of=config.fish
  ```

  Portably we could use something like this on the right side of pipeline:

  ```
  dd conv=notrunc seek=$(wc -c < testFile.txt) bs=1 of=testFile.txt
  ```

  Note the use of `bs=1` , which is to [prevent short reads from pipeline](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194848/295286)
- The `tee` command can be used when you need to append to file and send it to stdout or to next command in pipeline

  ```
  tee -a config.fish <<< "alias list='ls -cl --group-directories-first'"
  ```
- `awk` has append operator `>>` which is also portable and [defined by POSIX specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html)

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN{ printf "alias list=\x27ls -cl --group-directories-first\x27\n" >> "config.fish"  }'
  ```
- We can combine `sed`'s flag `$` to match the last line with `a` for appending and `-i` for in-place editing.

  ```
  sed -i '$a alias list='"'"'ls -cl --group-directories-first'"'" config.fish
  ```
- We could even implement something like `dd` in Python 3:

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    # read bytes from stdin, append to specified file
    import sys

    with open(sys.argv[1],'ab') as f:
         f.write(sys.stdin.buffer.read())
```

#### See also:

- [What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/678915/295286)
- [What is the differences between &> and 2>&1](https://askubuntu.com/a/635069/295286)
- [How to redirect stderr to a file](https://askubuntu.com/q/625224/295286)
- [What is the difference between “cat < filename” and “cat filename”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190700/295286)
- [What is the difference between “Redirection” and “Pipe”?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074550/295286)

Answer (score 8):

Adding to [Stefano's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/21559/301745), you can also use `cat`:

- Using a heredoc:

  ```
  $ cat >> config.fish <<'EOF'
  > alias list='ls -cl --group-directories-first'
  > EOF
  ```

  `<<'EOF'` means "take the following as input, until you reach a line that is just `EOF`". The quotes mean to take the input literally.
- Or inputting the line on stdin:

  ```
  $ cat >> config.fish
  ```

  Then paste or type in the line, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to a new line, then press Ctrl+D to mark the end.

Comment: I often use this method but recently got caught when I pasted in a text that included some (escape) codes. It didn't complain but when I checked the file there were chunks of pasted text missing. So use it with care!

Comment: @elmclose Sorry, which method? They work differently with respect to metacharacters. I think the second one doesn't do anything with them, though there might be a few exceptions.

Comment: I meant EOF method. Very convenient and useful when you type or paste in readable text. But codes in my text confused the process. The file was a bash script that kept failing. Took me a while before I discovered what had happened.