# Where I'm making the mistake in here document?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I read the use of [here document](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21596/how-do-i-use-bashs-operator). I tried something like this:

```
echo $* <<End  
anto  
End
```

What I'm trying here is, when I run this script rather than taking input from command line, I'm asking it to take *it* as `anto`. But this doesn't working for me.

I'm very new to bash scripting. Can anyone say, where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` doesn't read any information from stdin so you can't use a here-doc with it.

Use `cat` instead, like

```
cat<<End
anro
End
```