# What is the difference between "Redirection" and "Pipe"?

Tags: pipe, redirect

This question may sound a bit stupid, but I can not really see the difference between redirection and pipes.

Redirection is used to redirect the stdout/stdin/stderr, e.g. `ls > log.txt`.

Pipes are used to give the output of a command as input to another command, e.g. `ls | grep file.txt`.

But why are there two operators for the same thing?

Why not just write `ls > grep` to pass the output through, isn't this just a kind of redirection also? What I am missing?

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Pipe is used to pass output to another **program or utility**.

Redirect is used to pass output to either a **file or stream**.

Example: `thing1 > thing2` vs `thing1 | thing2`

`thing1 > thing2`

1. Your shell will run the program named `thing1`
2. Everything that `thing1` outputs will be placed in a file called `thing2`.  (Note - if `thing2` exists, it will be overwritten)

If you want to pass the output from program `thing1` to a program called `thing2`, you could do the following:

`thing1 > temp_file && thing2 < temp_file`

which would

1. run program named `thing1`
2. save the output into a file named `temp_file`
3. run program named `thing2`, pretending that the person at the keyboard typed the contents of `temp_file` as the input.

However, that's clunky, so they made pipes as a simpler way to do that. `thing1 | thing2` does the same thing as `thing1 > temp_file && thing2 < temp_file`

EDIT to provide more details to question in comment:

If `>` tried to be both "pass to program" and "write to file", it could cause problems in both directions.

**First example:** You are trying to write to a file.  There already exists a file with that name that you wish to overwrite.  However, the file is executable.  Presumably, it would try to execute this file, passing the input.  You'd have to do something like write the output to a new filename, then rename the file.

**Second example:** As Florian Diesch pointed out, what if there's another command elsewhere in the system with the same name (that is in the execute path).  If you intended to make a file with that name in your current folder, you'd be stuck.

**Thirdly:** if you mis-type a command, it wouldn't warn you that the command doesn't exist.  Right now, if you type `ls | gerp log.txt` it will tell you `bash: gerp: command not found`.  If `>` meant both, it would simply create a new file for you (then warn it doesn't know what to do with `log.txt`).

Comment: Thank you. You mentioned `thing1 > temp_file && thing2 < temp_file` to do more easier with pipes. But why not re-use the `>` operator to do this, e.g. `thing1 > thing2` for commands `thing1` and `thing2` ? Why an extra operator `|` ?

Comment: "Take the output and write it to a file" is a different action than "Take the output and pass it to a different program".  I'll edit more thoughts into my answer...

Comment: @JohnThreepwood They have different meanings. What if I wanted to redirect something to a file named `less`, for example? `thing | less` and  `thing > less` are perfectly different, as they do different things. What you propose would create an ambiguity.

Comment: Is it accurate to say that "thing1 > temp_file" is merely syntactic sugar for "thing1 | tee temp_file" ? Since finding out about tee I almost never use redirects.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat no, the `tee` command does something different.  `tee` writes output to both the screen (`stdout`) *and* the file.  Redirect does *only* the file.

Comment: Can I pipe as it is being outputted? Using | makes me wait for the first program to have terminated, I want to start piping as soon as there is any output.

Comment: @DidierA. I learned something :).   Yes, linux runs them concurrently.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37597/2688  Or trying running `(echo "one"; sleep 2; echo "test1"; sleep 2; echo "test2") | grep test`  and watch the timing of when the output shows up.

Comment: @DavidOneill Related, is there a difference between `cat file | cmd` and `<file cmd` w.r.t behaviour in any case?

Comment: @formulator Yes, difference is that with `<` command can use `lseek()` to jump to specific byte of file. This is faster. With `cat file | cmd` the command `cmd` cannot `lseek()` a pipe, since it's not a static object. If file is large this will be much much slower. So commands from pipes read everything sequentially, and in some cases have to read *everything* without discarting.

Comment: I've addressed the thing about overwriting commands in a comment to Florian's answer.  But to note also, if you're in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` you'd need write permissions on a file to overwrite it in the first place, like being logged in as root. So if you're doing that as regular user, this shouldn't be a problem. But then again you shouldn't do redirection inside important directories anyway, and check what files you're writing to before running a command.

Comment: to expand on this a bit: the `|` character creates a buffered unix pipe, which is an input/output queue that the next program in the pipeline can read from. stdout from one program is automatically mapped to stdin on the next program in the pipe. The `>` character operates on a file handle, there may be buffering on the fs for the file, but there is no buffering between output and the input target. It is possible to use redirects to specify input for other programs like so: `cat <(echo "output 1") <(echo "output 2")` ... here the output of the programs inside `<()` are treated as file handles.

Comment: I feel there couldn't have been a better explanation around this, especially with this amount of brevity.

Comment: @DavidOneill to make the answer even better can you write what is the difference of &> and > ?!

Comment: So it's all just a difference for better usability? Is there any difference in the implementation behind them?

Comment: contents starts from **First example:** are really confusing and bad I think. Which is the **First example:** you are referring to ? The command in the question or in your answer? And the following explanation are not good.

Comment: @Rick In "First Example" (and the others), I'm giving an example, not referring to one.

Comment: I wonder why "writing to a file" would be like: `thing1 | streamwrite log.txt` ? Than the > and < parameters would be superficial, but more important it would mean one could add another writing program (to do say formatting) and the command structure wouldn't change.

Comment: "pretending that the person at the keyboard typed the contents of temp_file as the input." This is incorrect. For example `cat <temp_file` is equivalent to `cat temp_file`. But if you type the content of `temp_file` as the input, i.e., `cat $(cat temp_file)`, the result is different.

Answer (score 33):

From the Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook:

> #### Redirection
>
> The shell interprets the symbols <,>, and >> as instructions to reroute a **command's** input or output to or from a **file**.
>
> #### Pipes
>
> To connect the STDOUT of one **command** to the STDIN of **another** use the | symbol, commonly known as a pipe.

So my interpretation is:  If it's command to command, use a pipe.  If you are outputting to or from a file use the redirect.

Answer (score 26):

If the meaning of `foo > bar` would depend on whether there is a command named `bar` that would make using redirection a lot harder and more error prone: Every time I want to redirect to  a file I first had to check whether there's a command named like my destination file.

Comment: This would be an issue only if you're  writing to `bar` in a directory that's part of your `$PATH` env variable. If you're in something like /bin, then ot could be a problem. But even then, `bar` would have to have executable permission set, so that shell checks not just for finding an executable `bar` but actually  can execute it.  And if the concern is with overwriting existing file, `noclober` shell option should prevent overwriting existing files in redirections.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy that's a whole lot of additional logical complexity, edge case consideration, destructive pitfalls, and bug potential for the negligible "gain"✝ of not having a 2nd operator solve all those problems at once. (✝Note: what does one even gain, really? 1 less line of code deep in some bash code somewhere that has no effect anywhere: no additional resource usage, negligible mental overhead, etc.)

Answer (score 20):

<sub>Note:The answer reflects my own understanding of these mechanisms up to date, accumulated over research and reading of the answers by the peers on this site and [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com), and will be updated as time goes on. Don't hesitate to ask questions or suggest improvements in the comments. I also suggest you try to see how syscalls work in shell with `strace` command. Also please don't be intimidated by the notion of internals or syscalls - you don't have to know or be able to use them in order to understand how shell does things, but they definitely help understanding.</sub>

#### TL;DR

- `|` pipes are not associated with an entry on disk, [therefore do not have an inode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302763/3701431) number of disk filesystem (but do have inode in [pipefs](https://www.linux.org/threads/pipefs-sockfs-debugfs-and-securityfs.9638/) virtual filesystem in kernel-space), but redirections often involve files, which do have disk entries and therefore have corresponding inode.
- pipes are not `lseek()`'able so commands can't read some data and then rewind back, but when you redirect with `>` or `<` usually it's a file which is `lseek()` able object, so commands can navigate however they please.
- redirections are manipulations on file descriptors, which can be many; pipes have only two file descriptors - one for left command and one for right command
- redirection on standard streams and pipes are both buffered.
- pipes almost always involve forking and therefore pairs of processes are involved; redirections - not always, though in both cases resulting file descriptors are inherited by sub-processes.
- pipes always connect file descriptors (a pair), redirections - either use a pathname or file descriptors.
- pipes are Inter-Process Communication method, while redirections are just manipulations on open files or file-like objects
- both employ `dup2()` syscalls underneath the hood to provide copies of file descriptors, where actual flow of data occurs.
- redirections can be applied "globally" with `exec` built-in command ( see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1027510/295286) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366228/85039) ), so if you do `exec > output.txt` every command will write to `output.txt` from then on. `|` pipes are applied only for current command (which means either simple command or subshell like `seq 5 | (head -n1; head -n2)` or compound commands (but also please note that for such compound commands the amount of bytes that `read()` consumes will influence how much data is left on the sending end of the pipe for other commands inside the read end of the pipe ).
- When redirection is done on files, things like `echo "TEST" > file` and `echo "TEST" >> file` both use `open()` syscall on that file ([see also](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067048/295286)) and get file descriptor from it to pass it to `dup2()`.  Pipes `|` only use `pipe()` and `dup2()` syscall.
- Redirections involve file and directory permissions; anonymous pipes typically do not involve permissions (i.e. whether or not you can or cannot create a pipe), but named pipes ( made with `mkfifo` ) do involve typical file permissions and read-write-execute bits.
- As far as commands being executed, pipes and redirection are no more than file descriptors - file-like objects, to which they may write blindly, or manipulate them internally (which may produce unexpected behaviors; [`apt` for instance, tends to not even write to stdout](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081342/295286) if it knows there's redirection).

#### Introduction

In order to understand how these two mechanisms differ, it's necessary to understand their essential properties, the history behind the two, and their roots in C programming language. In fact, knowing what file descriptors are, and how `dup2()` and `pipe()` system calls work is essential, as well as `lseek()`. Shell is meant as a way of making these mechanisms abstract to the user, but digging deeper than the abstraction helps understand the true nature of shell's behavior.

#### The Origins of Redirections and Pipes

According to Dennis Ritche's article [Prophetic Petroglyphs](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/mdmpipe.html), pipes originated from a [1964 internal memo](https://swtch.com/~rsc/thread/mdmpipe.pdf) by [Malcolm Douglas McIlroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_McIlroy), at the time when they were working on [Multics operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics). Quote:

> To put my strongest concerns into a nutshell:
>
> 1. We should have some ways of connecting programs like garden hose--screw in another segment when it becomes when it becomes necessary to massage data in another way. This is the way of IO also.

What's apparent is that at the time programs were capable of writing to disk, however that was inefficient if output was large. To quote Brian Kernighan's explanation in [Unix Pipeline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKzonnwoR2I) video :

> First, you don't have to write one big massive program - you've got existing smaller programs that may already do parts of the job...Another is that it's possible that the amount of data you're procesing would not fit if you stored it in a file...because remember, we're back in the days when disks on these things had, if you were lucky, a Megabyte or two of data...So the pipeline never had to instantiate the whole output.

Thus conceptual difference is apparent: pipes are a mechanism of making programs talk to one another. Redirections - are way of writing to file at basic level. In both cases, shell makes these two things easy, but underneath the hood, there's whole lot of going on.

#### Going deeper: syscalls and internal workings of the shell

We start with the notion of [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). File descriptors describe basically an open file (whether that's a file on disk, or in memory, or anonymous file), which is represented by an integer number. The two [standard data streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)  (stdin,stdout,stderr) are file descriptors 0,1, and 2 respectively.  Where do they come from ? Well, in shell commands the file descriptors are inherited from their parent - shell. And it's true in general for all processes - child process inherits parent's file descriptors. For [daemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) it is common to close all inherited file descriptors and/or redirect to other places.

Back to redirection. What is it really ? It's a mechanism that tells the shell to prepare file descriptors for command (because redirections are done by shell before command runs), and point them where the user suggested. The [standard definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_01) of output redirection is

```
[n]>word
```

That `[n]` there is the file descriptor number. When you do `echo "Something" > /dev/null` the number 1 is implied there, and `echo 2> /dev/null`.

Underneath the hood this is done by duplicating file descriptor via `dup2()` system call. Let's take `df > /dev/null`. The shell will create a child process where `df` runs, but before that it will open `/dev/null` as file descriptor #3, and `dup2(3,1)` will be issued, which makes a copy of file descriptor 3 and the copy will be 1. You know how you have two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, and when you do `cp file1.txt file2.txt` you'll have two same files, but you can manipulate them independently ? That's kinda the same thing happening here. Often you can see that before running, the `bash` will do `dup(1,10)` to make a copy file descriptor #1 which is `stdout` ( and that copy will be fd #10 ) in order to restore it later. Important is to note that when you consider [built-in commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) (which are part of shell itself, and have no file in `/bin` or elsewhere) or [simple commands in non-interactive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466496/85039), the shell doesn't create a child process.

And then we have things like `[n]>&[m]` and `[n]&<[m]`. This is duplicating file descriptors, which the same mechanism as `dup2()` only now it's in the shell syntax, conveniently available for the user.

One of the important things to note about redirection is that their order is not fixed, but is significant to how shell interprets what user wants. Compare the following:

```
# Make copy of where fd 2 points , then redirect fd 2
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/  3>&2  2> /dev/null
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 1 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 runner user 64 Sep 13 00:08 3 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 4 -> /proc/29/fd

# redirect fd #2 first, then clone it
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/    2> /dev/null 3>&2
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 1 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 2 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 3 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:08 4 -> /proc/31/fd
```

The practical use of these in shell scripting can be versatile:

- [saving output to variable of a program that only writes to stderr](https://askubuntu.com/a/704643/295286)
- [swapping stderr and stdout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42728/85039)
- [separating even input lines from odd input lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18904/85039)

and many other.

#### Plumbing with `pipe()` and `dup2()`

So how do pipes get created ? Via [`pipe()` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), which will take as input an array (aka list) called `pipefd` of two items of type `int` (integer). Those two integers are file descriptors. The `pipefd[0]` will be the read end of the pipe and `pipefd[1]` will be the write end. So in `df | grep 'foo'`, `grep` will get copy of `pipefd[0]` and  `df` will get a copy of `pipefd[1]`. But how ? Of course, with the magic of `dup2()` syscall. For `df` in our example, let's say `pipefd[1]` has #4, so the shell will make a child, do `dup2(4,1)` (remember my  `cp` example ?), and then do `execve()` to actually run `df`. Naturally, `df` will inherit file descriptor #1, but will be unaware that it's no longer pointing at terminal, but actually fd #4, which is actually the write end of the pipe. Naturally, same thing will occur with `grep 'foo'` except with different numbers of file descriptors.

Now, interesting question: could we make pipes that redirect fd #2 as well, not just fd #1 ? Yes, in fact that's what `|&` does in bash.  The POSIX standard requires shell command language to support `df 2>&1 | grep 'foo'` syntax for that purpose, but `bash` does `|&` as well.

What's important to note is that pipes always deal with file descriptors. There exists `FIFO` or [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), which has a filename on disk and let's you use it as a file, but behaves like a pipe. But the `|` types of pipes are what's known as anonymous pipe - they have no filename, because they're really just two objects connected together. The fact that we're not dealing with files also makes an important implication: [pipes aren't `lseek()`'able.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337739/85039) Files, either in memory or on disk, are static - programs can use `lseek()` syscall to jump to byte 120, then back to byte 10, then forward all the way to the end. Pipes are not static - they're sequential, and therefore you cannot rewind data you get from them with `lseek()`. This is what makes some programs aware if they're reading from file or from pipe, and thus they can make necessary adjustments for efficient performance; in other words, a `prog` can detect if I do `cat file.txt | prog` or `prog < input.txt`. Real work example of that is [tail](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c#n1834).

The other two very interesting property of pipes is that they have a buffer, which [on Linux is 4096 bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/85039), and they actually have a [filesystem as defined in Linux source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/pipe.c?id=HEAD) ! They're not simply an object for passing data around, they are a datastructure themselves ! In fact, because there exists pipefs filesystem, which manages both pipes and FIFOs,  [pipes have an inode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302763/3701431) number on their respective filesystem:

```
# Stdout of ls is wired to pipe
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/  | cat  
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:02 0 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:02 1 -> pipe:[15655630]
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:02 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 00:02 3 -> /proc/22/fd
# stdin of ls is wired to pipe
$ true | ls -l /proc/self/fd/0
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Sep 13 03:58 /proc/self/fd/0 -> 'pipe:[54741]'
```

On Linux pipes are uni-directional, just like redirection. On some Unix-like implementations - there are bi-directional pipes. Although with magic of shell scripting, you can make [bi-directional pipes on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53641/85039) as well.

#### See Also:

- [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465619/3701431)
- [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dup_(system_call)#dup2_for_input/output_redirection) of how pipeline is created in C using `pipe()` syscall and `dup2()`.
- [why pipes are used instead of input redirection](https://askubuntu.com/q/488382/295286)
- [What is the differences between &> and 2>&1](https://askubuntu.com/q/635065/295286)
- Redirections such as `<<`,`<<<` are implemented as anonymous (unlinked) temp files in `bash` and `ksh`, while `< <()` uses anonymous pipes ; [`/bin/dash` uses pipes for `<<`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337744/85039). See [What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/678915/295286)

Answer (score 14):

There's a vital difference between the two operators:

1. `ls > log.txt` --> This command sends the output to the log.txt file.
2. `ls | grep file.txt` --> This command sends the output of the ls to grep command through the use of pipe (`|`), and the grep command searches for file.txt in the in the input provided to it by the previous command.

If you had to perform the same task using the first scenario, then it would be:

```
ls > log.txt; grep 'file.txt' log.txt
```

So a pipe (with `|`) is used to send the output to other command, whereas redirection (with `>`) is used to redirect the output to some file.

Answer (score 4):

There's a big syntactic difference between the two:

1. A redirect is an argument to a program
2. A pipe separates two commands

You can think of redirects like this: `cat [<infile] [>outfile]`. This implies order doesn't matter: `cat <infile >outfile` is the same as `cat >outfile <infile`. You can even mix redirects up with other arguments: `cat >outfile <infile -b` and `cat <infile -b >outfile` are both perfectly fine. Also you can string together more than one input or output (inputs will be read sequentially and all output will be written to each output file): `cat >outfile1 >outfile2 <infile1 <infile2`. The target or source of a redirect can be either a filename or the name of a stream (like &1, at least in bash).

But pipes totally separate one command from another command, you can't mix them in with arguments:

```
[command1] | [command2]
```

The pipe takes everything written to standard output from command1 and sends it to the standard input of command2.

You can also combine piping and redirection. For example:

```
cat <infile >outfile | cat <infile2 >outfile2
```

The first `cat` will read lines from infile, then simultaneously write each line to outfile and send it to the second `cat`.

In the second `cat`, standard input first reads from the pipe (the contents of infile), then reads from infile2, writing each line to outfile2. After running this, outfile will be a copy of infile, and outfile2 will contain infile followed by infile2.

Finally, you actually do something really similar to your example using "here string" redirection (bash family only) and backticks:

```
grep blah <<<`ls`
```

will give the same result as

```
ls | grep blah
```

But I think the redirection version will first read all of the output of ls into a buffer (in memory), and then feed that buffer to grep one line at a time, whereas the piped version will take each line from ls as it emerges, and pass that line to grep.

Comment: Nitpick: order matters in redirection if you redirect one fd to another: `echo yes 1>&2 2>/tmp/blah; wc -l /tmp/blah; echo yes 2>/tmp/blah 1>&2; wc -l /tmp/blah` Further, redirection to a file will only use the last redirection. `echo yes >/tmp/blah >/tmp/blah2` will only write to `/tmp/blah2`.

Comment: Redirect is not actually argument to the program. The program will not know or care where its output goes (or input comes from).  It's just way of telling bash how to arrange things before running the program.

Comment: "simultaneously write each line to outfile and send it to the second cat": This doesn't work. You need `tee` for that

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, there are subtle semantic difference too - e.g. pipes close more readily than redirects:

```
seq 5 | (head -n1; head -n1)                # just 1
seq 5 > tmp5; (head -n1; head -n1) < tmp5   # 1 and 2
seq 5 | (read LINE; echo $LINE; head -n1)   # 1 and 2
```

In the first example, when the first call to `head` finishes, it closes the pipe, and `seq` terminates, so there's no input available for the second `head`.

In the second example, head consumes the first line, but when it closes it's own `stdin` *pipe*, the file remains open for the next call to use.

The third example shows that if we use `read` to avoid closing the pipe it is still available within the subprocess.

So the "stream" is the thing that we shunt data through (stdin etc), and is the same in both cases, but the pipe connects streams from two processes, where a redirection connects a streams between a process and a file, so you can see source of both the similarities and differences.

P.S. If you're as curious about and/or surprised by those examples as I was, you can get dig in further using `trap` to see how the processes resolve, E.g:

```
(trap 'echo seq EXITed >&2' EXIT; seq 5) | (trap 'echo all done' EXIT; (trap 'echo first head exited' EXIT; head -n1)
echo '.'
(trap 'echo second head exited' EXIT; head -n1))
```

Sometimes the first process closes before `1` is printed, sometimes afterwards.

I also found it interesting to use `exec <&-` to close the stream from the redirection to approximate the behaviour of the pipe (albeit with an error):

```
seq 5 > tmp5
(trap 'echo all done' EXIT
(trap 'echo first head exited' EXIT; head -n1)
echo '.'
exec <&-
(trap 'echo second head exited' EXIT; head -n1)) < tmp5`
```

Comment: "when the first call to head finishes, it closes the pipe" This is actually inaccurate for two reasons. One, (head -n1; head -n1) is subshell with two commands, each of which inherits read end of pipe as descriptor 0, and thus subshell AND each command have that file descriptor open. Second reason, you can see that with strace -f bash -c 'seq 5 | (head -n1; head -n1)'. So first head closes only its copy of file descriptor

Comment: Third example is also inaccurate, because `read` consumes only first line ( that's one byte for `1` and newline ). `seq` sent in total 10 bytes ( 5 numbers and 5 newlines ). So there's 8 bytes remaining in pipe buffer, and that's why second `head` works - there's data still available in pipe buffer. Btw, head exits only if there's 0 bytes read, kinda as in `head /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Am I understanding correctly that in `seq 5 | (head -n1; head -n1)` the first call empties the pipe, so it still exists in an open state but with no data for the second call to `head`? So the difference in behavior between the pipe and the redirect is because head pulls all the data out of the pipe, but only the 2 lines out of the file handle?

Comment: That's correct. And it's something that can be seen with `strace` command I gave in the first comment. With redirection, tmp file is on disk which makes it seekable ( because they use `lseek()` syscall - commands can jump around the file from first byte to last however they want. But pipes are sequential and not seekable. So the only way for head to do its job is to read everything first, or if file is big - map some of it to RAM via `mmap()` call. I once did my own `tail` in Python, and ran into exactly same problem.

Comment: It's also important to remember that read end of the pipe ( file descriptor ) is given to subshell first `(...)`, and the subshell will make copy of its own stdin to each command inside `(...)`. So they're technically read from same object. First `head`  thinks it's reading from it's own stdin. Second `head` thinks it has its own stdin. But in reality their fd #1 ( stdin ) is just copy of same fd, which is read end of the pipe. Also, I've posted an answer, so maybe it'll help clarify things.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer  to add the information we discussed in the comments into the actual answer itself ?

Answer (score 2):

I've hit a problem with this in C today. Essentially Pipe's have different semantics to redirects as well, even when sent to `stdin`. Really I think given the differences, pipes should go somewhere other than `stdin`, so that `stdin` and lets call it `stdpipe` (to make an arbitrary differential) can be handled in different ways.

Consider this. When piping one program output to another `fstat` seems to return zero as the `st_size` despite `ls -lha /proc/{PID}/fd` showing that there is a file. When redirecting a file this is not the case (at least on debian `wheezy`, `stretch` and `jessie` vanilla and ubuntu `14.04`, `16.04` vanilla.

If you `cat /proc/{PID}/fd/0` with a redirection you'll be able to repeat to read as many times as you like. If you do this with a pipe you'll notice that the second time you run the task consecutively, you don't get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

- The stuff on the right-hand side of `>` and `<` is expected to be a device name. Therefore the shell will take it literally and will not try to further evaluate it (except that you use [process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe), which itself is a named pipe). For example, `cat < a.txt` is equivalent to `cat a.txt`.
- The stuff on both sides of `stuff1 | stuff2` will be further evaluated by the shell. Conceptually, the output of `stuff1` will be recorded in a device, and the name of that device will be provided to `stuff2` as the last argument. If `stuff2` does not expect a device name as its last argument, you may get an error.

It is obvious that the piping `|` is more general than the rediection `>`.

From implementation point of view, piping uses more efficient way (buffering) to communicate the information and alows the piped commands to run cocurrently.

Two other operations that are worth being included in the comparison are:

- [Process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe)
- Command substitution

If you need to pipe the stdout of multiple commands, then you need to use Process Substitution.