# What does echo with ">>" symbol do?

Tags: command-line, bash

I've seen some command like

```
echo '* - nofile 65535' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

I know echo print something on  the screen.

and limits.conf was a file in that /etc/security path.

But want does `>>` do here? it means something like 'to' or 'in'?

Comment: Visit I/O redirection at http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`>>` redirects the output of the command on its left hand side to the end of the file on the right-hand side.

So,

```
echo '* - nofile 65535' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

will **append** `* - nofile 65535` to the end of the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, instead of printing `* - nofile 65535` on the screen.

If you instead had

```
echo '* - nofile 65535' > /etc/security/limits.conf
```

(note the `>>` replaced by `>`), everything already present in `/etc/security/limits.conf` would have been **replaced** by `* - nofile 65535`, and not appended.

You may also like to read this question:

- [Difference between "redirection" and "piping"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe)

Comment: Perfect, especially the extra '>' point. It helps me avoid possible disaster.