# How to redirect stderr to a file

Tags: command-line, redirect

While using nohup to put a command to run in background some of content appear in terminal.

```
cp: error reading ‘/mnt/tt/file.txt’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/mnt/tt/file.txt’: Input/output error
```

I want to save that content to a file.

Comment: @terdon This is a more specific question, and it rightly shows up in google search for the more specific question, which is a good thing.

Comment: @nroose yes, and it will keep showing up, that won't change. But any new answers should go to the more general question.

Answer (score 1086, accepted):

There are two main output streams in Linux (and other OSs), standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr). Error messages, like the ones you show, are printed to standard error. The classic redirection operator (`command > file`) only redirects standard output, so standard error is still shown on the terminal. To redirect stderr as well, you have a few choices:

1. Redirect stdout to one file and stderr to another file:

   ```
   command > out 2>error
   ```
2. Redirect stdout to a file (`>out`), and then redirect stderr to stdout (`2>&1`):

   ```
   command >out 2>&1
   ```
3. Redirect both to a file (this isn't supported by all shells, `bash` and `zsh` support it, for example, but `sh` and `ksh` do not):

   ```
   command &> out
   ```

For more information on the various control and redirection operators, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222).

Comment: So `hashdeep -rXvvl -j 30 -k checksums.txt /mnt/app/ >> result_hashdeep.txt 2> error_hashdeep.txt &` or `hashdeep -rXvvl -j 30 -k checksums.txt /mnt/app/ >> result_hashdeep.txt 2>&1` or `hashdeep -rXvvl -j 30 -k checksums.txt /mnt/app/ &> result_mixed.txt`

Comment: @AndréM.Faria yes. But the last two commands are equivalent, they will send both error and output to the same file.

Comment: As in the link you provided, I could use |& instead of 2>&1 they are equivalent, thanks for you time.

Comment: @terdon how do I redirect output to a file which has no "w" permission for others , I meant to ask can I redirect using `sudo` ? If so how can I do it ?

Comment: @benklein it works fine with the space, as do all similar shell operators. Something else must have gone wrong in your case.

Comment: @rohith I know this is a necro, but, you can do `command | sudo -S tee file > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @AndréM.Faria `|&` doesn't have wide support.

Comment: I couldn't get &> out to work in sh, only bash. Cron users beware, use 2>&1 instead.

Comment: @MikeMcKay yes, sorry, I didn't mention this since Ubuntu ships with bash as the default interactive shell. I have now added a note about that to the answer.

Comment: I want to point out that sh is often not a shell of its own. its usually actually another shell such as dash or bash. So your mileage with sh may vary.

Comment: Doesn't `2>` overwrite the file? That's not usually what anyone wants, especially an error log.

Comment: @Cerin yes, it overwrites the file. You can use `2>>` to avoid that. As for "usually", I use this most every day, sometimes I want to keep the previous log and sometimes I don't.

Answer (score 39):

First thing to note is that there's couple of ways depending on your purpose and shell, therefore this requires slight understanding of multiple aspects. Additionally, certain commands such as `time` and `strace` write output to stderr by default, and may or may not provide a method of redirection specific to that command

Basic theory behind redirection is that a process spawned by shell (assuming it is an external command and not shell built-in) is created via `fork()` and `execve()` syscalls, and before that happens another syscall `dup2()` performs necessary redirects before `execve()` happens. In that sense, redirections are inherited from the parent shell.  The `m&>n` and `m>n.txt` inform the shell on how to perform `open()` and `dup2()` syscall (see also [How input redirection works](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120566/295286), [What is the difference between redirection and pipe](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074550/295286), and [What does & exactly mean in output redirection](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031663/295286) )

#### Shell redirections

Most typical, is via `2>` in [Bourne-like shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/181255/kopciuszek), such as [`dash`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027519/295286) (which is symlinked to `/bin/sh`) and `bash`; first is the default and POSIX-compliant shell and the other is what most users use for interactive session. They differ in syntax and features, but luckily for us error stream redirection works the same (except the `&>` non standard one). In case of csh and its derivatives, the stderr redirection [doesn't quite work there.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35715/85039)

Let's come back to `2>` part. Two key things to notice: `>` means redirection operator, where we open a file and `2` integer stands for stderr file descriptor; in fact this is exactly how POSIX standard for shell language defines redirection in [section 2.7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.htm):

```
[n]redir-op word
```

For simple `>` redirection, the `1` integer is implied for `stdout`, i.e. `echo Hello World > /dev/null` is just the same as `echo Hello World 1>/dev/null`. Note, that the integer or redirection operator cannot be quoted, otherwise shell doesn't recognize them as such, and instead treats as literal string of text. As for spacing, it's important that integer is right next to redirection operator, but file can either be next to redirection operator or not, i.e. `command 2>/dev/null` and `command 2> /dev/null` will work just fine.

The somewhat simplified syntax for typical command in shell would be

```
 command [arg1] [arg2]  2> /dev/null
```

The  trick here is that redirection can appear anywhere. That is  both `2> command [arg1]` and `command 2> [arg1]` are valid. Note that for `bash` shell, there  there exists `&>` way to redirect both stdout and stderr streams at the same time, but again - it's bash specific and if you're striving for portability of scripts, it may not work. See also [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) and [What is the difference between &> and 2>&1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635065/what-is-the-differences-between-and-21/635069#635069).

*Note:* The `>` redirection operator *truncates* a file and overwrites it, if the file exists. The `2>>` may be used for appending `stderr` to file.

If you may notice, `>` is meant for one single command. For scripts, we can redirect stderr stream of the whole script from outside as in `myscript.sh 2> /dev/null` or we can make use of [exec built-in](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027519/295286). The exec built-in has the power to rewire the stream for the whole shell session, so to speak, whether interactively or via script. Something like

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2> ./my_log_file.txt
stat /etc/non_existing_file
```

In this example, the log file should show `stat: cannot stat '/etc/non_existing_file': No such file or directory`.

Yet another way is via functions. As [kopciuszek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/181255/kopciuszek) noted in his answer, we can write function declaration with already attached redirection, that is

```
some_function(){
    command1
    command2
} 2> my_log_file.txt
```

#### Commands writing to stderr exclusively

Commands such as `time` and `strace` write their output to stderr by default. In case of `time` command, the only viable alternative is to redirect output of whole command , that is

```
time echo foo 2>&1 > file.txt
```

alternatively, synchronous list or subshell could be redirected if you want to separate the output ( as shown in [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356654/3701431) ):

```
{ time sleep 1 2> sleep.stderr ; } 2> time.txt
```

Other commands, such as `strace` or `dialog` provide means to redirect stderr. `strace` has `-o <filename.txt>` option which allows specifying filename where output should be written. There is also an option for writing a textfile for each subprocess that `strace` sees. The `dialog` command writes the text user interface to stdout but output to stderr, so in order to [save its output to variable](https://askubuntu.com/a/704643/295286) ( because `var=$(...)` and pipelines only receives stderr ) we need to swap the file descriptors

```
result=$(dialog --inputbox test 0 0 2>&1 1>/dev/tty);
```

but additionally, there is `--output-fd` flag, which we also can utilize. There's also the method of named pipes. I recommend reading the linked post about the `dialog` command for thorough description of what's happening.