# bash - return and print statement

Tags: bash

I have a bash function that returns a number by adding 20 to it. At the same time, I would like to display to see what is the input.

```
function add_nos {
    echo "$1"
    echo $(($1 + 20))
    return 1
}

result=`add_nos $1`
echo $result
```

When I run the following command -

```
bash setup.sh 10
```

I get the following output -

```
10 30
```

How can I differentiate between the 2 stmts; ie 1st echo is for debug and 2nd echo is for return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe print the debug statement to standard error instead of standard output?

```
echo "$1" >&2
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Return

The `return` value is stored in $? after every command/function call. Try this to access it:

```
function add_nos {
    echo "$1"
    echo $(($1 + 20))
    return 1
}

result=`add_nos $1`
retval=$?  # this is the "return" value of "add_nos"
echo "result: $result"
echo "return: $retval"
```

See [the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-return). Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419952/difference-between-return-and-exit-in-bash-functions/4419956) and [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions).

#### Stderr

As another answer suggested, [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) is a good place to send debug output. You can also do a lot more than just a return value. Try this:

```
function add_nos {
    echo "input: $1" >&2
    echo $(($1 + 20))
    echo "done now!" >&2
}

echo "starting script" >&2
result=`add_nos $1`
echo "result: $result"
```

Then run it with and without debug output by [redirecting](https://askubuntu.com/a/625230/582404) [stderr](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
$ bash setup.sh 10  
starting script
input: 10
done now!
result: 30

$ bash setup.sh 10 2>/dev/null
result: 30

$ bash setup.sh 10 2>logfile
result: 30

$ cat logfile
starting script
input: 10
done now!
```