# how input redirection works?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, scripts, redirect

On my understanding, any command that reads from standard input (i.e keyboard), that it gets its input from a file.

```
$echo < text_content.txt

$
```

But echo command does not read and display the text_content.txt on the terminal. what's wrong here?

Comment: `echo` does not read from stdin.  `cat` does.  Try `cat <text_content.txt` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### stdin and Commands

> On my understanding, any command that reads from standard input (i.e keyboard), that it gets its input from a file.

Effectively, yes. As I've discussed in my answer on [What characterizes a file in Linux/Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500907/85039), a file is any object on which you can execute standard operations such as `read()`, `open()`, `write()`, `close()`. `stdin` being represented via file descriptor 0 is effectively a file in that regard, and any command/process in Linux gets 3 standard file descriptors - stdin,stdout,stderr - when that process is started. What are the actual files behind those file descriptors ? The command doesn't care and shouldn't, as long as it can do operations on it.

> But echo command does not read and display the text_content.txt on the terminal. what's wrong here?

Now, command is free to do what it will with those file descriptors<sup>1</sup>. In case of `echo` it only deals with `stdout` and doesn't perform any action on `stdin` at all. So there's nothing wrong with the command itself.

`<` redirection will `open()` the file `text_content.txt` for reading, and it still will assign file descriptor ( for example 3 ) returned from `open()` call to file descriptor 0, and if a command is concerned with stdin - it will read from file descriptor 0 as if nothing happened.In fact, you will see that in action, if you run `strace -f -e dup2,write,openat bash -c 'echo < text_content.txt`

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY) = 3
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Notice the `dup2()` system call. That's how file descriptor 3 (the file) is assigned/redirected. In sort of `cp original copy` syntax, `dup2(3,0)` makes a copy of file descriptor 3 to file descriptor 0, and they point to same file.

Notice also that `write()` output a newline to file descriptor `1`. That's the default behavior. If we do `strace -f -e dup2,write,openat bash -c 'echo FOO < /etc/passwd'` here's what we will see

```
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
write(1, "FOO\n", 4FOO
)                    = 4
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So again, nothing wrong here - redirections are performed properly and `echo` does its job of writing stuff to `stdout` which is file descriptor 1.

---

#### How to actually read a file

Now, lets address something else. How can we read a file in shell ? Well, for that there exists `cat` command, which accepts arguments, so you can do just `cat file.txt`. Can you do `cat < file.txt` ? Sure. But that means shell will have to do that `dup2()` call, whereas `cat file.txt` doesn't - so there's less unnecessary syscalls is what I'm saying.

In complex cases, such as when you need to perform an action on each line of the file, you would do

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    # command to process line variable here
done < /etc/passwd
```

Now, for the whole loop file descriptor `0` will be a copy of whatever file descriptor is returned from opening `/etc/passwd`.  Of course, if you can use `cat` or another specific command to the job of reading a file - do that. Shell is slow method and has a lot of pitfalls. See also, [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/85039)

---

<sup>1. Some applications still might care about what they can do with stdin or detect if stdin is a file or pipeline. When `stdin` file descriptor is assigned as read-end of pipeline (which is also a file descriptor) the output is not seekable (meaning that application written in C or another language cannot use `seek()` syscall to quickly navigate to specific byte offset in a file). A good example of that is given in the question titled [What is the difference between “cat file | ./binary” and “./binary < file”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337750/85039)</sup>

Sidenote: on Linux it's not exactly keyboard from where stdin gets its input. If you do

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/0
lrwx------ 1 serg serg 64 Feb 23 16:45 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/0
```

you will see in the output that it is `/dev/pts/0` terminal device to which `stdin` points initially. The terminal device then interfaces with keyboard, or it could as well be serial cable.

Additionally, if file is not very large, you could take advantage of `bash`'s `mapfile` builtin to read lines into array:

```
mapfile  -t  < /etc/passwd
for i in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```