# How to print any text using terminal in ubuntu18.10

Tags: gnome-terminal, 18.10

I am a new UBUNTU browser, so that I have fave so many problems however I loved using it.
I want to know that-"How to print any text or any String using terminal in Ubuntu 18.10 as Output in the terminal".

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to print something in terminal is to either use `echo` or `printf` command.

```
echo foo
printf '%s\n' "foo"
```

For long texts - it depends. Texts of multiple lines that you construct yourself can be printed via multiple ways, one of which is just to run `cat` and type in text which will be output on the terminal with each line and stop that via Ctr+D ;  another one is here-document structure.

```
$ cat  <<EOF
> This is one line
> this is another
> EOF
```

The `<<` designates [here-document](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/678919#678919) and `EOF` serves as text terminator (and it can be any string so long as it's the same one). `cat` can be used to print text files, but in this case it prints `stdin` stream - one of 3 streams that each process inherits. `stdin` is typically connected to current terminal device, but in this case because we use here-doc it has been altered to read the temporary file which shell creates on our behalf when we use `here-doc` ( [see also](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120566/295286) a question why this wouldn't work with `echo` ). Of course printing text file can be as simple as `cat file.txt`, but more often you want to *do* something with that text, and for that purpose there's multiple utilities and commands.

---

Of course printing **any** string can be a challenge. Does your terminal support printing/recognizing different locales (that is languages ?). Is the text file properly encoded ? There's plenty of considerations to take. But if you're just starting with Ubuntu, `echo` will be enough for sometime. Eventually, when you'll start working with multiple Linux/Unix systems you will learn that [printf is better than echo](http://Why%20is%20printf%20better%20than%20echo?) for making portable scripts.