# Nautilus can set desktop wallpaper. How can it set login and lock screen wallpaper?

Tags: scripts, nautilus, login, desktop-background, lock-screen

In Nautilus there is a menu option to use the current image as desktop wallpaper:

[image: Nautilus Wallpaper]

How can I use the current image as wallpaper for the Login screen and Lock screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using Nautilus to navigate and view an appropriate .png or .jpg file to use as login screen and lock screen wallpaper, Nautilus can set this for you using a script:

[image: Set Login Wallpaper.gif]

**Note:** In Ubuntu 18.04 only the lock screen wallpaper is changed. A different technique will be required to change the login wallpaper.

To create the script use:

```
cd ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
gedit set-login-wallpaper
```

Paste in these lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## Set login wallpaper

# strip new line char passed by Nautilus
FILENAME=$(echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | sed -e 's/\r//g')

# Multiple files can't be selected.
LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l <<< "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
LINE_COUNT=$((LINE_COUNT-1))

if [[ $LINE_COUNT > 1 ]] ; then
    zenity --error --text "Ony one file can be selected at a time! "
    exit 1
fi

# Object type must be "file..." (ie no directories, etc.)
if [ -d "${FILENAME}" ] ; then
    zenity --error --text "$FILENAME is a directory!";
    exit 1
else
    if [ -f "${FILENAME}" ]; then
        : # Bash noop
    else
        zenity --error --text "${FILENAME} is not a file!";
        exit 2
    fi
fi

# Build working file in /tmp
echo "[com.canonical.unity-greeter]" > /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp
echo "draw-user-backgrounds=false" >> /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp
echo "background='$FILENAME'" >> /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp

# Must run as sudo
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ] ; then

    # Get sudo password
    PASSWORD=$(zenity --password --title="Set Login Wallpaper" --timeout=20)

    # copy working file to real file using sudo
    echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S cp /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp \
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override

    # compile using sudo
    echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas

else
    # Already sudo so simply copy and compile
    # copy working file to real file
    cp /tmp/set-login-wallpaper.tmp \
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override

    # compile
    glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
fi

exit 0
```

Save the file and exit the `gedit` editor.

Now mark the script as executable using:

```
chmod +x set-login-wallpaper
```

Open Nautilus and navigate to your directory with wallpaper images. Find an appropriate image and right-click on it. This drop-down menu appears:

[image: Nautilus Right Click Drop Down]

Click on the third option `Scripts`. Another drop down menu appears with all your scripts:

[image: Nautilus set-login-wallpaper Drop Down]

Select `set-login-wallpaper`.

When the script runs you will have to enter your `sudo` password.

Reboot and enjoy your new login wallpaper.

Comment: You need `gksu` as well for `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` part. Also, note that this approach does change login ( greeter ) wallpaper, but not lock-screen.  I've written a script for that in the past, so feel free to search through my answers

Comment: I had two lines of `gksudo` during development phase but added shortcut at last minute merging two lines into one. I've revered back to original version where password has to be entered twice (which) I still like to change. **It does change Lock Screen too**-- at least on my Ubuntu 16.04. I've just retested it twice.

Comment: well, I've solved that problem a while ago.  http://askubuntu.com/q/746350/295286    In fact, you're basically re-doing the same thing I've already done like almost year ago. https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/chgreeterbg.sh

Comment: Part I - I've seen similar stuff around but this is running in GUI not terminal. Part II - Nice script. Trivial point line #71 should say "check if root, else prompt for sudo password" and not "...quit". After work I'll do some more googling for GUI password. I know the -a (askpass) parameter can be used in conjunction with Zenity. Just need to invest more time.

Comment: Principles are the same - just substitute `pkexec` or `gksu` instead of `sudo` - and there's your GUI. Line  #71 was relevant before - I changed code without changing the comment. Thanks for pointing out though - I should correct that

Comment: I like `pkexec` better than `gksu` because it doesn't dim all screens when prompting for password. However I've only setup policy kits for `gedit` and `nautilus` would I have to do that all over again for `cp` and `glib-compile...`?  Also others likely don't have `pkexec` setup and I want to stay as mainstream as possible with public code. Wish I could change it all now, but it'll have to wait until tonight :(

Comment: `pkexec` works sort of like `gksu` by default. I've not set up anything, and still use it to authenticate via some scripts. I don't know about your setup though, so i've no idea if that would affect it.