# Nautilus right click script for base64

Tags: command-line, scripts, 16.10, nautilus-actions, nautilus-script

i would like to add nautilus script for right click,like convert selected file with base64 but no luck.Regular command in terminal is like:

```
base64 input.jpg output.txt
```

This is my closest script to do it;

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_Path" | base64 > Base64
```

But it gives the path of file as base64.
Can anybody help me about this?

Comment: I think your problem is related to _echoing_ the path instead of usinf the variale content as an argument. Also your variable name has a typo, it's `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` _(I think in you real script is ok, because you could obtain the file path)_. You can use `base64 "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" > "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS".b64`, but better take a look at proposed answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you can already add custom script to nautilus and only need the right script to do the actual work, if that be the case then try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generating base64 files from nautilus
m=0 # counter
while [ -n "$1" ] && [ -f "$1" ] 
do
   echo " " >> output.txt     
   echo "$1" >> output.txt
   base64 "$1" >> output.txt
   echo " " >> output.txt
   m=$(($M + 1))
   shift
   echo " " >> output.txt           
done
zenity --info --text="Operations finished and "$m" file(s) encoded"
exit 0
```

Please make file executable with:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

Explained:

1. `-n "$1"` checks if the values are greater than 0, ie not 0
2. `-f "$1"` checks if file exists and is regular file.
3. `shift` moves through the given arguments
4. `m=$(($m + 1))` adds `1` to `0` initial count value to keep track of number of files being converted
5. `zenity` displays a dialogue box to indicated end of operations.

Comment: The `echo` won't let you see what is happening in the classic sense. You can find out after the fact by looking in `/var/log/syslog`. To see what is happening in real time you need to use `zenity` with `--info` option as the GUI interface from your script.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thanks will improve my answer but note just learning scripting :).

Comment: @ George I've seen your many great posts and edits here in AU. I have an example of zenity here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu/837115#837115. Also for scripting in Nautilus here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/871312/nautilus-can-set-desktop-wallpaper-how-can-it-set-login-and-lock-screen-wallpap/871313#871313

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the _zenity_ is installed by default right and one just needs to use is as in the links you provided ?

Comment: I believe `zenity` is installed by default. It might be Debian / Ubuntu only default though. It is an upgrade to  `xmessage` which is very difficult to use on high-dpi monitors.

Answer (score 3):

Your original script has a couple issues:

- `"$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_Path"` should be all capitalized and spelled differently, as in "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS".
- `echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | base64` will only encode the string "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" and that's it. If you want to encode a file, you need to pass that variable on via `xargs` or better yet - pass it directly. `base64` can take files as  arguments , thus `base64 "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"` is what you really want to do. No pipes here, no `echo`.

Below I provide alternative and fairly simplistic approach

#### Script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for item in "$@"
do
   file=$(basename "$item" )
   base64 "$item" > "$HOME/$file.base64"
done
```

#### Instructions

- Place this file into `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` directory
- ensure it is executable with `chmod +x  <path to script here>` command.
- Select the files that you want, right click , and go to scripts submenu. Select your script.
- Once the the script is done, each base64 encoded file will be placed into your home folder, with original filename and `.base64` extension. You may wish to alter the script to create `.base64` files in the same directory, which is totally fine, but it might be a problem if you do not have permission to create files in that directory.

  Of course this script is slightly simplistic. I've created a bit more involved script in Python3 , which you can find on my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/nautilus_scripts/blob/master/base64_encode.py) for nautilus scripts. It does a bit more than the other scripts -  checks for file type, show info and error popups,etc.

Comment: Thank you,i am very appreciated,that was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @elanozturk  You're welcome, and thank you for the good question !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all guys,i did two scripts with your help and suggestions for encode and decode.

**Encode:**

```
#!/bin/bash
for item in "$@"
do
   mkdir /yourpath/encode
   file=$(basename "$item" )
   base64 "$item" > "/yourpath/encode/$file-base64"
done
```

**Decode:**

```
for item in "$@"
do
   mkdir /yourpath/decode
   file=$(basename "$item" )
   name=`echo $file | cut -f1 -d'-'`
   base64 -d "$item" > "/yourpath/decode/$name"

done
```