# Bash: sudo -S <<< "mypassword" - interactive shell issue

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, redirect

I'm trying to use `sudo` with `-S` to issue the password via command line.

```
$ sudo -S <<< "mypassword" command
```

This works, but it doesn't allow for interactive commands. Like `nano` for example:

```
$ sudo -S <<< "mypassword" nano /tmp/foo
```

It automatically closes the nano session. Same with `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo -S <<< "mypassword" apt-get install foo
```

It closes before I can press "y" to install foo. I know I can pass `-y` with apt but overall, this is frustrating.

Also tried stuff like this, but it still fails to engage with interactive session:

```
$ sudo -S <<< "mypassword" -H -u root bash -c "apt-get install foo"
```

Is it possible to use `-S` with sudo without cancelling all interactive shells?

Comment: Since with `-S` you're telling `sudo` to read from stdin, effectively blocking the child command's access to stdin. Why do you want to use `-S` and not a `NOPASSWD` rule?

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, passing passwords in such way is bad idea for security reasons. Passwords can be intercepted  and they get stored into shell's history as well. See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/184158/121824

Answer (score 6):

#### File descriptors are inherited

What you're using is `<<<` aka [here-string](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286), and that type of redirection is implemented via temporary files that are immediately unlinked (aka deleted). Knowing also that processes inherit file descriptors (and stdin among them)<sup>1</sup> from parent to child, when `sudo -S` is performed, it reads its input from the temporary file that your original shell has passed to it (the one that reads `sudo -S` command). You can see that in action:

```
$ sudo -S bash -c 'ls -l /proc/self/fd/0' <<< "mypasswd"
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Feb 26 13:12 /proc/self/fd/0 -> '/tmp/sh-thd.cUOOXU (deleted)'
```

Thus, `nano` reports `Too many errors from stdin` error in such case. What can be done is to manually re-wire where `stdin` is coming from.

```
$ sudo -S bash -c 'exec < /dev/tty; nano /tmp/foobar' <<< "mypasswd"

$ sudo -S bash -c 'nano /tmp/foobar < /dev/tty' <<< "mypasswd"
```

Either of the two commands will lauch `nano` properly and other commands as well. [`/dev/tty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514853/3701431) is the special file representing current terminal device, and it is effectively the same thing as `stdin` of "normal" interactive shell (and of course I am oversimplifying that statement).

Another variation on the theme is `$ sudo -S bash -c 'nano /tmp/foobar 0>&1' <<<"mypasswd"`. `stdout` effectively points to the same terminal device (unless you've explicitly provided a redirection to have stdout point somewhere else). Thus, if we make `stdin` point to be the `dup`licate of `stdout`, it's effectively the same solution as above. (And if you're wondering why I highlighted `dup` part, that's because `dup2()` syscall is the one responsible for all the juggling of file descriptors under the hood)

---

#### Caution

However, note that I don't encourage using `sudo -S` in interactive shell, since passwords will remain in shell's history

```
$ sudo -S bash -c 'sleep 3m' <<< "ohnomypassword"
^C
$ history 2
 2016  sudo -S bash -c 'sleep 3m' <<< "ohnomypassword"
 2017  history 2
```

`sudo -S` is more appropriate for use with other processes, where `sudo -S` would expect input via pipeline, ideally from `zenity --password` or `dialog --passwordbox "foobar text" 200 200` (see [extra1](https://askubuntu.com/a/704643/295286) and [extra2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213497/85039) about dialog).

---

<sub>1. If file is open with `O_CLOEXEC` flag set, the child process or replaced process spawned via `execve()` type of flag won't have access to that file descriptor - that is it will be closed on `execve()`</sub>