# How to execute a task in background?

Tags: command-line, background-process

Is it possible to run a task or script started from terminal at the background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple answers here, depending on what you want (this answer is valid in `bash` and `zsh` shells, others may vary).

If you need to run a command in background and you know it before running it, simply add a `&` at the end of the command (using `sleep 60`, do nothing during 1 minute, as example command):

```
[romano:~] % sleep 60 &
[1] 9054
1& [romano:~] %
```

If you have already run it, you can stop it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, and when the shell gives you a prompt, you can background it with the command `bg`:

```
1& [romano:~] % sleep 60  
^Z
[1]  + 9084 suspended  sleep 60
1z [romano:~] 20 % bg
[1]  + 9084 continued  sleep 60
1& [romano:~] %
```

In both cases, the process/job is still attached to your terminal; if you close your terminal a *hangup* (HUP) signal is sent to the process --- most process will gracefully exit then. If you need to ensure that the process will continue, you can either start it with:

```
nohup sleep 60 &
```

or, after having sent it to background with `bg` or with a simple `&`, tell the shell to forget about it, with:

```
disown %%
```

(`%%` is a [job control](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php) shortcut, and here stands for the last process sent in background).

Then you have to take account of the output of the process --- in the first two cases the output will still arrive to the terminal; in the case of `nohup` it will be diverted on a file called `nohup.out`, and in the latter case (with `disown`) it will go to the terminal unless you close it, in which case the behavior is quite undefined. It is good practice to take care yourself of the output of a background process using [redirection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe).

Answer (score 5):

add `&` to the command.

Example:

```
$ cp FromA ToB &
```

Answer (score 2):

This example will run updates in the background:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y &
```

Just note the singe &.
If you want to hide the stdout, do following:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y > /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it more advanced, and want to be able to use the session later locally or by SSH, you can use screen.

```
# screen
# apt-get update -y
```

Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd>.

Later you can reattach:

```
# screen -rd
```

Comment: This was very clear & helpful.