# apt-get returns [x] yyyy and stalls during download

Tags: command-line, apt

When issuing:
`sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

The console returns:

```
[1] 3854
```

And starts the procedure, but stalls after:

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

When trying from different SSH sessions the `[X] YYYY` is different. Reboot doesn’t fix the issue.

Does the `[X] YYYY` refer to a lock from a previous update?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Did you issue `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade -y` literally? The ampersand should be doubled (`&&`) to do what you probably wanted. Instead, you seem to have got a [task in background](https://askubuntu.com/q/562911/250300).

Comment: yes, the single & seemed to be the reason to my struggles - I have been searching for many things, not realizing that my problem was something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` operator is specially used for executing a task in background, representing like you see (with the `[X] YYYY`). *YYYY* is the **PID number** of the task in background, and *X* is the number you assigned at this background task (like a counter).

PID will change every time, it will increment itself like a counter, and X would be reset when you will close the terminal. If you type `kill -9 YYYY` where *YYYY* is the PID number of this background task; terminal will prompted `[X] Stopped`, that means your background task is ... stopped.

There is no problem with that, just a little mistake from your command, which would be `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`.

NB: Usually, when you use a command line (without the `&` operator), you can't use another one in the same terminal unless the command line is done, but when you add the `&` operator, the terminal will accept another command at same time (but without output and error redirection, it can be hard to type something, so you can also use `nohup`).

Comment: AFAIK the PID numbers are not random, see [How do Linux PIDS increment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179612/54675).

Comment: @Melebius i correct my answer