# tee and output redirection

Tags: command-line

```
ls -l *.txt | wc -l | tee count.txt
ls -l *.txt | wc -l > tee count.txt
```

I am learning basic Unix commands. I thought those two commands mentioned would do the same thing, but they do not. Only the first command writes to count.txt. How come the output redirection used in the second command is not doing anything?

Comment: If we refactor your question a little, this has been [perfectly ansywered](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe) already here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ls -l *.txt | wc -l | tee count.txt
```

**In first example:**

The `ls` command lists all files in the current directory that have the filename extension `.txt`, one file per line; this output is piped to `wc`, which counts the lines and outputs the number; this output is piped to `tee`, which writes the output to the terminal, and writes the same information to the file `count.txt`. If `count.txt` already exists, it is overwritten.

**In your second example:**

```
ls -l *.txt | wc -l > tee count.txt
```

In this example `tee` will be treated as **file name** instead of a command and output of `wc -l` will be redirected to the newly crated file `tee` and will  contain the output of `wc -l` and string `count.txt`.

*If you want the same behaviour as in the first example then right way of doing this would be:*

```
 ls -l *.txt | wc -l > count.txt
```

`>` itself is sufficient to redirect the output to `count.txt` file

Comment: In the second example, are you saying it's ambiguous because the output from wc -l is not piped?

Comment: @Mint.K your second example is a comepletely diferent command. It means "save the output of `wc -l` in a file called `tee`" and doesn't involve the `tee` command in any way.

Comment: You're right. I just noticed my second command made a file called tee with the output of wc -l in it.