# What is | in terminal command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I've been trying to learn how to use apt-get in Ubuntu and I came across this command on a [how to geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/63997/how-to-install-programs-in-ubuntu-in-the-command-line/)

```
sudo dpkg –list | less
```

So this basically lets us look at a list of packages we have installed in our machine and "scroll through the list"

My Question in is, what is the `|` charactere there? Right before `less`, What is it's purpose, I'm just trying to understand the syntax of the command. Why isn't it just another option, like `-less`?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/172982/295286 It's called pipe. Really important and one of the most useful features of command line

Comment: Let me grab the occasion to mention MS-DOS also supported the same pipe but since it was a single task OS, it buffered the output of the first program and when it finished then it handed it over to the second while in Unix -- which is multitasking -- the second program can process the output of the first while the first produces more output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|` also known as pipe.

Pipe is used to take the output to use in another command.

For example when we you use this command `echo "ubuntu" | grep u`, the output of echo "ubuntu" is sent to grep program.

Answer (score 6):

`|` is called **pipe**. The pipe operator passes the output of one command as input to another. A command built from the pipe operator is called a pipeline.

In UNIX like operating systems, a pipeline is a sequence of processes chained together by their standard streams, so that the output of each process feeds directly as input to the next one.

Suppose, you have `$ command 1 | command 2 | command 3`, then

[image]

*Source: [Using Pipes with Linux Commands](http://www.d3noob.org/2016/03/using-pipes-with-linux-commands.html)*

For example, if you want to list all files in a folder, you will probably use the following:

```
$ ls -la
```

Now, suppose, you want to list only java source files, you would probably do something a follows:

```
$ ls -la | grep .java
```

`ls -la` produces a process, the output of which is *piped* to the input of the process for `grep .java`.

You can learn more about pipes and filters [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-pipes-filters.htm).

Answer (score 2):

**`|` is an operator called `Pipe`:**

When you need the output from `command 1` for the input into `command 2`, then you would use `pipe` character '|'. Here is the syntax for the pipe character:

```
command | command
```

**Example:**

```
rahul@VM:~$ ls | sort
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
examples.desktop
Music
Pictures
Public
Templates
Videos
```

The above example is using the output from `ls` as input to the `sort` command. You will notice the list has been sorted.

As you can see, the command line is an easy and powerful way of completing many tasks

Ref:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandlineHowto

Comment: Your title says "The Command is called pipe". Pipe is not a command. It's an operator. There's a significant difference.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: Ohh yeah. Thanks for pointing out.