# Bash file redirection bug?

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout

From what I understand about program IO, there are `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` data streams (and a return code). `stdout` and `stderr` are the two data output streams. So if I use bash redirection to close one of the output streams, I can narrow down which stream that text is being sent to. Right?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I'm running into this bizarre issue with bash redirection.

Let me explain the example. Here is my command:

```
# apt-cache show php5
N: Can't select versions from package 'php5' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
# |
```

The `php5` package does not exist on Ubuntu 18.04 so `apt-cache` displays an error. I would assume this text is sent to the `stderr` stream, so I attempted to close that stream:

```
# apt-cache show php5 2>&-
# |
```

It appears this verifies that the text was sent through `stderr`. All good so far! But now as a sanity check, I tried closing `stdout` (I should see the error text now):

```
# apt-cache show php5 1>&-
# |
```

What!? I redirected `stdout` this time but `stderr` is also not showing up?

According to the internet, I have my file descriptors correct: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

I can't figure out what could be going on here.

Screenshot proof:

[image: Bash redirect bug]

Comment: `apt-cache` seems to realize its output is being redirected. I get different output from `apt-cache show nonexistent` and `apt-cache show nonexistent | cat`, for example.

Comment: @wjandrea Possible. I've been looking at different forms of redirection. What seems to happen is that `N: ` lines get written to stdout and `E: ` lines go to `stderr`, but when  `stderr`  is redirected `apt`  hides both  for whatever reason. Tracing the  syscalls, however, shows that for some reason `write()` call for either line always goes to fd 2, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It's not `bash`, it's `apt-cache` that's messing around with file descriptors.

`apt-cache` is doing something very interesting - it tends to **not** write out lines starting with `N:` characters intended for stdout.

Consider this:

```
$ apt-cache show nonexistent
N: Unable to locate package nonexistent
E: No packages found
```

We see two lines, one starting with `N:` one starting with `E:`. `N:` lines go to stdout. In your example, you have two `N:` lines.

```
# apt-cache show php5
N: Can't select versions from package 'php5' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

If you trace the system calls via `strace -e write -f bash -c 'apt-cache show randomtext >&-'` you'll see that writing `E:` lines happens, but `N` lines aren't there:

```
[pid 12450] write(2, "E", 1E)            = 1
[pid 12450] write(2, ": ", 2: )           = 2
[pid 12450] write(2, "No packages found", 17No packages found) = 17
[pid 12450] write(2, "\n", 1
)           = 1
[pid 12450] +++ exited with 100 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12450, si_uid=1000, si_status=100, si_utime=5, si_stime=2} ---
+++ exited with 100 +++
```

So `apt-cache` is smart enough to check for redirected stdout. But what about `stderr` ? Apparently writes are still there: if you do 
`strace -e write,openat,dup2 -f bash -c 'apt-cache show randomtext 2>&-` you'll see that `apt-cache` opens `/dev/null` to still have something present for `stderr`:

```
[pid 12543] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 2
....
[pid 12543] write(2, "N", 1)            = 1
[pid 12543] write(2, ": ", 2)           = 2
[pid 12543] write(2, "Unable to locate package randomt"..., 35) = 35
[pid 12543] write(2, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid 12543] write(2, "E", 1)            = 1
[pid 12543] write(2, ": ", 2)           = 2
[pid 12543] write(2, "No packages found", 17) = 17
[pid 12543] write(2, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid 12543] +++ exited with 100 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12543, si_uid=1000, si_status=100, si_utime=5, si_stime=3} ---
+++ exited with 100 +++
```

---

If you perform the same with other programs in bash, it works as expected:

```
# stdout closed, stderr not
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd >&-
ls: write error: Bad file descriptor
# stdout open , stderr closed, and it's number is assigned to whatever command is trying to open - in this case /proc/self/fd directory
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd 2>&-
total 0
lrwx------ 1 xie xie 64 Oct  6 11:32 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 xie xie 64 Oct  6 11:32 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 xie xie 64 Oct  6 11:32 2 -> /proc/12723/fd
```