# What do the letters stand for in APT errors?

Tags: apt

If I run `apt-cache show nonexistent`, I get this error:

```
N: Unable to locate package nonexistent
E: No packages found
```

I know the E stands for "Error", and a W would stand for "Warning", but what does the N stand for? "Information"?

Are there other letters that may show up?

I couldn't find anything in [`man apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html), [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html), or [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-get.8.html).

P.s. This came up because of this question: [Bash file redirection bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1081337/301745)

Comment: I guess it's "Note".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letters designate error message type. By looking at the `apt-cache` [C++ source code](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/master/cmdline/apt-cache.cc) and the [related `error.cc` file](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/contrib/error.cc#L58), there's apparently different types of errors:

- `GEMessage(FatalE, FATAL)`
- `GEMessage(Errno, ERROR)`
- `GEMessage(WarningE, WARNING)`
- `GEMessage(NoticeE, NOTICE)`
- `GEMessage(DebugE, DEBUG)`

The errors are pushed onto message stack via [`_error->Insert` method](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/cacheset.cc#L775) which in the apt-cache source is apparently an "alias" for [`GlobalError::Insert` method](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/contrib/error.cc#L137).

Interestingly enough there's also [CacheSetHelper](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/cacheset.cc#L911) which sets whether to show errors or not. That defaults to showing errors in the [constructor](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/master/apt-pkg/cacheset.h#L56) for this class, and message type to ERROR.

Comment: So the letters are **F**atal, **E**rror, **W**arning, **N**otice, and **D**ebug, right? That's what I ultimately want to know.

Comment: Essentially, yes.  Different story is to figure out how `apt`  decides what makes a message error rather than warning. In the yesterday's question OP has `N: No packages found`, but your command has `E: No packages found`.  But there's way too much C++ source code to read :)

Comment: To my experience the classification of messages as error, warning, etc. often also depends on the author who wrote that particular piece of code. ;-)