# "No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu" during installation

Tags: system-installation

I'm fairly new to learning about computers. I have a self-built computer and while installing Ubuntu (my first operating system) I run into a dialog.

I press <kbd>install now</kbd> and it replies

> no root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu

The partition table button is grayed out and the only thing I can do is press the change button. The change button crashes it so I can't continue and I have no options to press.

Answer (score 1):

[Root filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) defines topmost entry point on disk where operating system should be installed, and denoted by `/`. In the Windows world, that's `C:\` and in Minix - `>`. In the picture [from related post](https://askubuntu.com/a/343352/295286) the disk is subdivided into several partitions, and root filesystem is on `/dev/sda5`.

[image]

Of course you can do a lot of fancy things with that: root filesystem can be on one disk or partition and `/home` can be placed on another partition or whole different disk entirely.

If you're not using anything fancy, selecting Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu in the menu should be enough. If it still doesn't let you install, select Something Else and in the next menu click `+` button to create new root partition. For more detailed steps follow the linked post.

Fun things for more advanced learning:

Note that "filesystem" in general denotes disk or memory space (for example `tmpfs` or `ramfs`) which are organized on the level of bits and bytes in particular way to store files (and also preserve their integrity as in case of `ext4` journaling filesystem). Filesystems intended for user access(aka browsing files), however, need to be connected to a folder so that users can access the contents of filesystem. This is called [mounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)). In this case, root filesystem is mounted at `/` folder by convention, although there's other much more technical ways in which a root filesystem can be mounted on some other folder such as `chroot`.

However, there's difference between filesystems for users access ( aka userspace ), and kernel space. Such kernel filesystems as [`pipefs`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074550/295286) don't have any folder available to users to browse, and generally have FS_NOMOUNT flag set([source](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-3.html)).

Comment: I'm looking at that image except there is no /dev/sda. There is nothing in that area below the words Device Type Mount point. Its blank, and above it is blank as well, also when I press change, +, or - it freezes then crashes. My picture won't upload or it would be easier to see. Also my understanding of programming or most of this is minimal, please excuse me for that. And finally I read how I'm suppose to be able to select something else if there is no operating system on the computer, it never game me that option

Comment: @CharlesDelPapa  If it doesn't see the disk that may be a bad sign. You might want to check if the disk is OK.  If you have a spare hard drive, try replacing current disk with the spare one.  And for starters just go through the installation process with the very first option. If you do need to keep some data on the disk, then best to back it up first, or go into manual partitioning and resize the existing partition so it doesn't take up as much space.

Comment: I dont have a spare as this is brand new. I suppose if that's the problem I'll need another, thankyou for the help

Comment: @Charles Before writing it off as broken, try to connect it to another computer. Sorry can't help much more