# Communicating via a local socket or named pipe

Tags: networking, ssh, pipe, sockets

I'm reading a book that is related SSH. I can't figure out what this sentence means.

> SSH clients communicate with the agent via a local socket or named
>   pipe whose filename is stored in an environment variable, so all
>   clients (and all other processes) within your login session have
>   access to the agent.

"via a local socket or named pipe", what does it mean?

Comment: Local sockets are one way for different applications on the same machine to communicate. Named pipes are another way. Shared files are yet another way. Dbus is yet another way. There are many possible ways for two applications on the same machine to talk to each other. In this case, the communicating applications seem like the SSH client and the SSH agent.

Answer (score 1):

Let's answer couple questions first:

- **What is a named pipe ?**  It's an inter-process communication method. Anonymous pipelines are created in software, typically via `pipe()` syscall. When you do a pipeline in shell like `/bin/echo foo | grep 'foo'` you're asking shell to execute that `pipe()` call, make two subprocesses, and make those two subrocesses ( in this case `/bin/echo` and `grep` ) talk to  each other.  Of course, because that type of pipe is anonymous, there's no name for it in the filesystem on disk ( there is a file in kernel's virtual filesystem, but that's another story). Named pipes aka FIFO can be created with `mkfifo` command or `mkfifo(3)`/`mkfifoat(3)` syscalls. For example, `mkfifo /tmp/my_named_pipe.fifo`. So instead of doing `echo foo | grep 'foo'` in same terminal, you can do `echo foo > /tmp/my_named_pipe.fifo` and have `grep 'foo' /tmp/my_named_pipe.fifo` in another terminal

  So basic idea is of a pipe is to have two endpoinds - one for writing and one for reading. In case of named pipe you have one command/process writing to that FIFO file and one - reading from that file.
- **What is a socket**: A  [network socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) is basically software channel or a reference , using which processes on the same or different machine can communicate.  A socket by itself doesn't do much, but if it is bound to network port ( like port 80 for HTTP or port 554 for RTSP media stream ) processes on the same or different machine - then your software can talk to other software.

  Basic idea is similar: make a named socket, like `/tmp/my_socket.sock` and have two or more command talk via this socket (writing AND reading), usually with one command being "server" and always listening on that socket.
- **How does any of this relate to SSH ?** By default `ssh` server runs on port 22 and there will be a network socket allocated for that( remember what I said about socket having port ?). Sometimes it is useful to make SSH tunnel. For example,  if we have this setup

  ```
  Client Computer A -> Firewall Linux Server B ->  Linux Server with Website C
   IP: 172.16.127.1      IP: 172.16.127.2(ssh port 22)    IP: 172.16.127.3 (website on port 80)
  ```

  and we want to have secure connection from Client A to Website C, we would do in `ssh`:

  ```
  ssh  -L 172.16.127.1:8877:172.16.127.3:80 my_username@172.16.127.2
  ```

  This is called port forwarding: now you can open in browser `http://172.16.127.1:8877` on Computer A and it will redirect to website on Linux Server C. Note that 8877 is random unused port. If the port is already in use - you may want to find a different unused port, anything above 1000 should be fine.

  Of course this is not always convenient as it will keep session open. And this is where you could create a named socket aka [Unix Domain Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) 　[and control ssh session in background without having to have shell open.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83806/how-to-kill-ssh-session-that-was-started-with-the-f-option-run-in-background)

So this is where we can answer the actual question related to the quote from the book you mentioned:

- **ssh-agent**:  In certain situations we don't want to want to store ssh credentials  on the server we're trying to connect to. This is why you'd run an [SSH agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) software (for Windows you could use Pageant aka PuTTY Agent). The `SSH_AUTH_SOCKET` (for example `SSH_AUTH_SOCKET=/tmp/my_auth.sock` ) environment variable will have the Unix Domain Socket path via which the `ssh` command can talk to the agent, and confirm that your login is proper. This would be useful in my previous example, if we want to make sure that connection to Linux Firewall Server B is authentic - the username is who they really are - then you'd use an ssh agent on Computer A.

  And this is very useful if we have many  Servers C and many Firewall Servers B - storing passwords on many Server B machines is not secure nor practical.

There's a lot more to sockets, pipes and `ssh` , but hope this helps to briefly clarify what things are and how they relate to each other. See my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074550/295286) about pipes vs redirection, which explains pipelines in a lot, a lot more detail