# Send a string and Enter key to a Node.js script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process, nodejs

I am running a Node.js script that prompts (via [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer#inquirerpromptquestions---promise)) user for a code. I get the process id of the script:

```
pgrep -f test.js
```

and then pass it the code with a new line to simulate Enter key:

```
echo -e "1234\n" > /proc/88888/fd/0
```

The code `1234` gets passed, a new line is added as well, but it didn't trigger Enter key and the script does not proceed. However, when I manually press Enter key in shell, the script does recognise the Enter key. So the question is how can I reliably send Enter key to another process/script?

Comment: could you share the file you are feeding data to? so that any possible solution can be tested ?

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

is that you are a bit confused about the usage of pipes and redirections.

- **Pipe** `|` is used to pass output to another program or utility.
- **Redirect** `>` is used to pass output to either a file or stream.

A more detailed answer about pipes and redirections [is given here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe)

### The Solution

Since now we know that we need to use pipes here, something like this would solve the problem.

```bsh
echo -e "1234" | /proc/88888/fd/0
```

### Tests

I ran the script you have provided in the question, and the following are the output screenshots.
[image: Local Screenshots of script]