# What is the differences between &> and 2>&1

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

There are two forms of redirection the **standard output** and **standard error** into **standard output**. But which one is better? and why the `&>` is considered the perfect?

I can't find what is the differences so that many tutorials and even bash manual state that  `&>` is better!

So Why shall I use `&>` and not `2>&1`

Mainly using `bash` shell

---

EDIT: Thanks for commentors

Only >& works in csh or tcsh

In ksh only 2>&1 works.

dash use >file 2>&1 redirection only

Then which one to use to ensure my script is compatible with other systems whatever the used shells are!

Comment: the better one is what does what you need to do.  these do very different things.  which shell are you using?

Comment: @Skaperen using bash

Comment: what do *you* want to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to know what is the differences, What I want is dont in both but i just need to know if the is a difference so that once is preffred over other

Comment: `&> somewhere` is just bash shorthand for `> somewhere 2>&1`: in the words of the bash manual, they are  *"symantically equivalent"*

Comment: For portability, use `>file 2>&1`

Comment: @Maythux see my edit to the answer

Comment: I'm on Mobile so can't post full code but I'm sure you will get what I'm trying to say

Comment: @Maythux Just to comment on your question about which variant to use . . . Some scripts actually test environment variables  for which shell is running the script. I would suggest testing the shell and conditionally running redirection that is suitable. Alternatively , require specific shell via shebang line and just use the redirection you want

Comment: thanx! helpful article. one thing to add. ">file 2>&1" outputs both std and err messages to the file, "2>&1 >file" outputs err to the console and std to the file.

Answer (score 37):

Bash's man page mentions there's two ways to redirect [stderr and stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams):
`&> file`  and `>& file`. Now, notice that it says both stderr and stdout.

In case of this `>file 2>&1` we are doing redirection of stdout (1) to file, but then also telling stderr(2) to be redirected to the same place as stdout ! So the purpose may be the same, but the idea slightly different. In other words "John, go to school; Suzzie go where John goes".

What about preference ? `&>` is  a `bash` thing. So if you're porting a script, that won't do it. But if you're 100% certain your script will be only working on system with bash - then there's no preference

Here's an example with `dash` , the Debian Amquist Shell which is Ubuntu's default.

```
$ grep "YOLO" * &> /dev/null
$ grep: Desktop: Is a directory
grep: Documents: Is a directory
grep: Downloads: Is a directory
grep: Music: Is a directory
grep: Pictures: Is a directory
grep: Public: Is a directory
grep: Templates: Is a directory
grep: Videos: Is a directory
grep: YOLO: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
```

As you can see, stderr is not being redirected

To address your edits in the question,  you can use if statement to check $SHELL variable and change redirects accordingly

But for most cases `> file 2>&1` should work

---

In more technical terms, the form `[integer]>&word` is called [Duplicating Output File Descriptor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_06), and is a feature specified by POSIX Shell Command Language standard, which is supported by most POSIX-compliant and Brourne-like shells.

See also [What does & mean exactly in output redirection?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031663/295286)

Comment: Then what happens when using on some other shells?

Comment: zsh supports `&>` .... @Maythux In shells that do not support `&>` e.g. `dash` you need to use the trivial `>file 2>&1` redirection..

Comment: Then Which one to use if I want to be sure my script will be compatible with different shells

Comment: @Maythux Use `>file 2>&1` . This work on all the shells

Comment: I do believe bash (Borne Again SHell) is the default in Ubuntu, not dash. Both are included, but when a new user is created, bash is set by default as the user's shell in /etc/passwd, unless otherwise specified when the accout is created (or changed after creation). I'm sure there's some way to override that behavior, but it's still Ubuntu's default.

Comment: @TSJNachos117 shells set in `/etc/passwd` for each user are interactive shells.  System scripts are usually for `dash`  unless otherwise specified.   As for what is default, it's determined by what is symlinked to `/bin/sh` In Ubuntu's case that's `dash`.  In RHEL it's is `bash`, in FreeBSD it is `tcsh` [source](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/shells.html) and [another source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Answer (score 11):

I would generally recommend following the [Bourne-again SHell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))'s way of doing things, since bash is arguably the most popular Unix shell out there. Bash typically uses either `&>` or `2>&1`. IMHO, neither is "perfect", so I recommend forgetting about that nonsense. Realistically, which one you should use depends on what you are trying to do.

`2>&1` merges stderr with stdout, which can be useful if, for example, you want to pipe stderr text. So, for example, if you want to see if a program prints a certain stderr message, but don't want your screen filled with (presumably) unimportant garbage, you could do something like `program 2>&1 | grep crashed`, which will search the stdout and stderr from a program called "program" for the word "crashed".

On the other hand, if you don't want a program to print anything at all, you could simply run `program &> /dev/null`, which will redirect both stderr and stdout to /dev/null, a special file which magically makes things disappear. Or, if you want to save the output of a program (perhaps to report a bug or something), you could redirect both stderr and stdout to a file: `program &> log.txt` will redirect all data to a file called "log.txt". If you wanted to, you could redirect the stdout and stderr via `program 2> log.txt > log.txt` or `program 2>&1 | cat > log.txt`, both of which would have the same effect as using `&>`. If you do something like `program 2>&1 > file`, only stdout will be redirected, but stderr can still be piped to another program, such as cat, which could be redirected as shown above. However, typing `&>` is easier than any of the above examples, since it involve typing fewer characters (and it's a bit easier for human beings to read). Do note that `program 2> log.txt > log.txt` might be more likely to work on non-bash shells.

PS: if you are worried about people using other shells, there's something you can add to be first line of your script called a "magic number", or "shebang". This is essentially a way to make sure other computers (particularly those running Unix-like operating systems) know which program to use to execute a script. Different scripts use different shebangs. A shebang for a bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If you use the above as the first line of a given script, bash will generally be used to execute said script. This will make it much more difficult for someone to accidentally execute the script with the wrong shell.

PS: I'm not going to lie: up till now, I didn't know one could use `>&`, but, as far as bash goes, it seems to do the same as `&>`. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: While I do agree with you about use of `#!` line to explicitly request `bash` , it is not always available on other systems. Very often developers/sysadmins  have to write portable scripts for systems on which `bash` may not be available and it may not be under their control to  install `bash` .  The `>file 2>&1` is just much portable.

Comment: You made a reversal error above, which does not produce the result you claim or want.  Redirect stderr to stdout, then redirect stdout leaves stderr on the original stdout.

Comment: Serg: I didn't mean to imply bash was universal. However, I think more people are using it than say (t)csh. If you don't know what someone else is using, and have to make a blind guess, bash is probably your best bet. Also, I generally don't know about portability, since I only use bash. The fact that `>file 2>&1` is more portable is good to know. I'll make an edit to reflect that.

Comment: Ubfan1, thanks for the info. I would never have guessed in a million years that bash wouldn't redirect stderr to a file in that case. I've just edited my answer to prevent others from making the same mistake.

Answer (score 6):

> So Why shall I use &> and not 2>&1

`2>&1` is standard Bourne/POSIX shell.

`&>` is a bash extension and not *de jure* standard.

If you write scripts using bash extensions, sooner or later you're going to encounter head-scratching failures with cryptic syntax error messages because they're being run in a standard shell.

Answer (score 5):

From [Bash Reference Manual -> 3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error):

> This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and
>   the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the
>   file whose name is the expansion of word.
>
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard
>   error:
>
> ```
> &>word
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> >&word
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred. **This is semantically
>   equivalent to**
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```
>
> When using the second form, word may not expand to a number or ‘-’. If
>   it does, other redirection operators apply (see Duplicating File
>   Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.

Also good to refer to [Greg's wiki on Input And Output -> 4.2. File Descriptor Manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Descriptor_Manipulation):

> For convenience, Bash also makes yet another form of redirection
>   available to you. The &> redirection operator is actually just a
>   shorter version of what we did here [ `2>&1` ]; redirecting both
>   stdout and stderr to a file.