# What does & mean exactly in output redirection?

Tags: command-line, redirect, io

I see stuff like `command 1> out` or with `2>&1` to redirect stderr, but sometimes I also see `&>` by itself, etc.

What is the best way to understand `&` and what it means exactly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `&` in `2>&1` simply says that the number `1` is a file descriptor and not a file name. In this case the `standard output file descriptor`.

If you use `2>1`, then this would redirect errors to a file called `1` but if you use `2>&1`, then it would send it to the `standard output stream`.

This `&>` says send both, `standard output` and `standard error`, somewhere. For instance, `ls <non-existent_file> &> out.file`. Let me illustrate this with an example.

Setup:

1. Create a file `koko` with the following content:

   ```
   #!bin/bash

   ls j1
   echo "koko2"
   ```
2. Make it executable: `chmod u+x koko`
3. Now note that `j1` doesn't exist
4. Now run `./koko &> output`
5. run `cat output` and you will see

   ```
   ls: cannot access 'j1': No such file or directory
   koko2
   ```

Both, `standard error` (`ls: cannot access 'j1': No such file or directory`) and `standard output` (`koko2`), were sent to the file `output`.

Now run it again but this time like so:

```
./koko > output
```

Do `cat output` and you will only see the `koko2` like. But not the error output from the `ls j1` command. That will be sent to the `standard error` which you will see in your terminal.

Important note thanks to @Byte Commander:

Note that in `command >file 2>&1` the order of the redirection is important. If you write `command 2>&1 >file` instead (which is normally not what you want), it will first redirect the command's `stdout` to the file and after that redirect the command's `stderr` to its now unused `stdout`, so it will show up in the terminal and you could pipe it or redirect it again, but it will not be written to the file.

Comment: What is `&>` mean?

Comment: Is it fair to say that the ampersand in `&1` and the ampersand in `&>` are unrelated?  Seems like the second use is more of an 'and' use, where the first case is more of a special identifier.

Comment: No it's a `BASH` specific notation for both `standard error and output` as stated by ByteCommander. That `&` is used to identify a file descriptor, remember `BASH` behaves a bit differently from it `sh` which it's master per say

Comment: There's a couple more meanings of the ampersand: start in background, e.g. `sleep 235 &`, logical AND: `commandA && commandB`. These are unrelated to IO redirection though.

Comment: @Ruslan OP is specifically talking about `file discriptors`

Comment: Note that in `command >file 2>&1` the order of the redirections is important. If you write `command 2>&1 >file` instead (which is normally not what you want), it will first redirect the command's stdout to the file and after that redirect the command's stderr to its now unused stdout, so it will show up in the terminal and you could pipe it or redirect it again, but it will not be written to the file.

Comment: yes @ByteCommander I am aware of that will add it to my answer

Comment: "That will be sent to the `standard output` which you will see in your terminal." shouldn't this be "to the `standard error`"?

Comment: Yes @frarugi87 your right corrected

Comment: @George wow, you were fast ;) Good work

Answer (score 7):

`> FILE 2>&1` and `&> FILE` are equivalent. See [8.2.3.2. Redirection of errors](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html#sect_08_02_03_02) of in [Bash Guide for Beginners Chapter 8](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

Comment: IIRC `&> FILE` is only specific to Bash whereas `>FILE 2>&1` is understood by a greater number of shells.

Comment: @ByteCommander, ohh, I didn't even know bash had such a shorthand... I've always used 2>&1.

Answer (score 2):

The `[n]>&word` is called **Duplicating Output File Descriptor**(see [section 2.7.6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) of POSIX Shell Language Standard). This particular behavior is feature of bourne-like shells, including `ksh`, `dash`, and `bash`; in fact, the standard is based around Bourne shell and `ksh`. Looking into [tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) and [csh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) manuals, they apparently do not provide capability of duplicating any file descriptor, however from the description of `>&`, this behaves as `&>` in `bash` (that is, redirects errors and normal output to file).

In *nix like systems, including Ubuntu, you often hear that everything is file, or rather a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). The standard output is constant file descriptor 1 and standard error is file descriptor 2. So, `> FILE 2>&1` technically means duplicate file descriptor 2 onto file descriptor 1. In other words of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11636056/3701431) :

> The 2>&1 tells the shell to give the command a file descriptor 2 that is a duplicate of descriptor 1. (i.e stderr & stdout point to same fd).

The key here is to note that descriptor 1 has to be set first. Because shell processes redirections in left to right order, the `command >FILE 2>&1` tells shell to rewire stdout for `command` to go into `FILE` first, and only then descriptor 2 can become copy of 1, that is 1 and 2 point to same location - `FILE`.

This of course goes beyond the standard error and standard output. As show in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248013/85039), by doing `3&>2`

> ...you duplicate (dup2 ) filedescritor 2 onto filedescriptor 3, possibly closing filedescriptor 3 if it's already open

Example of  manipulating file descriptors, among many, would be [capturing output of `dialog` command into variable](https://askubuntu.com/q/491509/295286)

It's also worth noting that `&>` is specific to `bash`. In [`zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) this behaves the same, but according to documentation, "...does not have the same effect as ‘> word 2>&1’ in the presence of multios". In POSIX compliant `/bin/sh`, this is would be treated as regular redirection with putting command into background. See also, [Is there any sh code that is not syntactically valid bash code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443123/85039).

See also:

- [Greg's Wiki: File Descriptors](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor)