# understanding bash redirection using > char

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I am learning bash and am not able to understand what is going wrong with the output redirection in the following example:

I have a file called myfile.txt with the following content.

*Practice makes Perfect*

I am going to use `tr` command to replace **P** with **p**:

```
cat myfile.txt | tr P p
```

This does what I want, now I am going to put the result back into the original file:

```
cat myfile.txt | tr P p > myfile.txt
```

But after executing the above command myfile.txt is empty... why is this happening?

---

Update:

If I send the output to a different file, then it works as expected:

```
cat myfile.txt | tr P p > anotherfile.txt
```

Comment: You should not use the same file for input and output. What you are doing is open a file for reading, and then create a new file with the same name for writing the result into it. Try also this `cat myfile.txt | tr P p >> myfile.txt`. Appending to a file does not create a new file, and in that case the content is not deleted. Well, it gets repeated with `tr P p` altered content.

Comment: It's because the shell opens `myfile.txt` for writing and truncates it **first** - see for example [Warning regarding ‘>’](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/65304)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash (and other POSIX-compliant shells) follow two  rules that explain this behavior:

- Redirection happens before commands run.
- If a file exists, it is truncated (emptied) when redirection goes to the file as in `> myfile.txt`.

So because there is `>` redirection the contents of the `myinput.txt` get discarded and `cat` prints nothing, `cat` exits and closes the pipe and `tr` closes the file without writing anything to it. Order in which commands start is not particularly important ( and it is not guaranteed, see [Gille's answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/85039)). But what is important is that redirection occurring before commands starting; that is each command's standard streams are prepared, and that's what causes empty file in the end.

But it is possible to [edit the same file](https://serverfault.com/questions/135507/linux-how-to-use-a-file-as-input-and-output-at-the-same-time)  tools like `sponge`, just not in this particular case.

See also:

- [Redirection executed before a command](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061622/295286)

Answer (score 0):

Use: sort -o instead of redirection. I n such a way you will be able to write to the same file.

```
cat myfile.txt | tr P p | sort -o myfile.txt
```

Comment: I'd suggest `sponge` command instead. `sort`  will do sorting which will change order of lines. I'd also be careful with race condition. In this case because of 3 pipes, `sort` can read `stdin` into buffer without interfering with `cat`, but if it's a large file, data may be lost partially. About `sponge`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207921/85039

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion cat is not used in the correct intention. Normally cat is used to combine files, but often also misused to just use display simple files.

In your case I would use the tr command in the following way:

```
tr P p < myInput.txt > myOutput.txt
```

Comment: `> myOutput.txt` opens file for writing, and if it exists truncates the contents. The contents of the file will be blank after this command