# Is `printf >&2` equivalent to `echo >&2`?

Tags: bash, scripts

This isn't a question of `printf` vs `echo`.

I'm trying to edit my script to use `printf` exclusively, and I have the following in my code:

```
echo >&2 'Failed to initialize REPL repo. Please report this!'
```

If I replace `echo` with `printf`, will it introduce any side effects (because of the `>&2`)?

```
printf >&2 'Failed to initialize REPL repo. Please report this!\n'
```

I couldn't find an answer in askubuntu. Either there isn't one or the search is ignoring the `>` and `&` characters.

Comment: My question is fine. I do not need convincing of using one over the other, I need to know what happens when I replace `echo` with `printf` in that particular line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A redirection like `>&2` is a feature of the shell running your script, the program whose output gets redirected is not relevant for it. Yes, if you only ask about the redirection, that’s the same – you don’t have to worry about it unless you change the shell. See your shell‘s manual for details about this feature, e.g. [`man bash`/REDIRECTION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#redirection) for `bash`.

There’s a nice answer about the differences between `echo` and `printf` over on Unix & Linux: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/246819)

As for why you can’t search for symbols on AU, see this meta Q&A:
[How to search AU for a string containing “$”?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18014/507051)

Comment: Thank you, the reason for my doubts was all articles including the one you linked show examples like `echo >&2` but not `printf >&2`. Your explanation for `>&2` is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> If I replace echo with printf, will it introduce any side effects (because of the >&2)?

The `>&2` part has nothing to do with either `echo` nor `printf`. The `>&` is a shell redirection operator, where in this case it duplicates `stdout` (implied, though could be referenced explicitly with `1>&2`) of the command to `stderr` ( file descriptor 2).  They can appear in any order in a command in bourne-like shells. The only issue that can happen is with `csh` shell and its derivatives(see [related post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031663/295286)). So, so long as you are using bourne-like shells ( `dash`, `bash`, `ksh` ) you should be fine.

As for `printf` vs `echo` generally `printf` is preferred because it's more portable. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/85039)