# What does 2>&1 means in crontab commands?

Tags: cron

I've seen many crontab commands written this way:

```
*/5 * * * * ~/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Can someone explain what is the exact meaning of `2>&1`?

Comment: It's been explained so many times already, I can't believe you haven't searched.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean

Comment: Also this https://askubuntu.com/a/1031663/295286

Answer (score 6):

It's redirecting standard error to standard output using file descriptors.

This isn't a cron construct but a shell construct and is available in pretty much any shell you may come across.  `2` is the file descriptor for STDERR and `1` is the file descriptor for STDOUT.  The `>` sign is the redirection operator.

More information about file descriptors and shell redirection can be found [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).