# What does >&2 mean in a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I am doing my homework and I have a question about one line. I don't understand what this `>&2` means:

```bash
if test -d $2 
  then echo "$2: Is directory" >&2 ; exit 21
fi
```

Comment: What does **hw** stand for in your question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix probably **h**ome**w**ork ...

Comment: @steeldriver Well in that case +1 for honesty!

Comment: **Voting to Reopen** neither the question nor any of the answers contain `>&2`.

Comment: Related: [What does & mean exactly in output redirection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959066/what-does-mean-exactly-in-output-redirection)

Comment: Do not forget to accept answer you consider more appropriate.

Answer (score 19):

File descriptor 1 is `stdout` and File descriptor 2 is `stderr`.

Using `>` to redirect output is the same as using `1>`. This says to redirect `stdout` (file descriptor 1).

Normally, we redirect to a file. However, we can use `>&` to redirect to `stdout` (file descriptor 1) or `stderr` (file descriptor 2) instead.

Therefore, to redirect `stdout` (file descriptor 1) to `stderr` (file descriptor 2), you can use `>&2`.

For more information:

- [File descriptor (Computer Hope)](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/file-descriptor.htm)
- [Understanding Shell Script's idiom: 2>&1 (by Brian Storti)](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/)
- [3.6 - Redirections (GNU Bash reference manual)](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)
- [I/O Redirection (The Linux Document Project)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#IOREDIRECTIONREF1)

Answer (score 11):

It is simply displaying the message "`/blah/blah/: Is directory`" to `stderr`. Also known as **Standard Error** which is denoted by `&2`.

Without the `&2` messages are displayed on `stdout`. Also known as **Standard Output** which is denoted by `&1`.

More details on displaying messages to `&>2` can be found here:

- [Bash command that prints a message on stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643165/bash-command-that-prints-a-message-on-stderr)
- [echo >&2 “some text” what does it mean in shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489934/echo-2-some-text-what-does-it-mean-in-shell-scripting)

In your command posted, both messages for `stdout` and `stderr` will appear on your terminal screen. However some applications will separate the `stderr` messages and perform special processing.

Most people don't bother redirecting `echo` error messages to `>&2` but it is technically the correct way of doing things.

---

For more reading on `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` from user or system administrator perspective see:

- [Confused about stdin, stdout and stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr)

For a programmers perspective of stdin, stdout, stderr which are &0, &1 and &2 respectively see:

- [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdin.3.html)

Answer (score 3):

So `if test -d $2` Means if $2(the second argument) is a directory, then

`echo "$2: Is directory" >&2`  means print $2: is directory,

and `>&2` means send the output to STDERR, 
So it will print the message as an error on the console.

---

You can understand more about shell redirecting from those references:

- https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections
- https://amrbook.com/linux/shell-script/shell-scripting-pipes-and-redirection/