# Single command to open various applications

Tags: command-line, nautilus, gedit

Usually, before beginning my coding duty I open the following:

- google-chrome
- nautilus
- terminal
- system monitor
- gedit

Is there a way to open all of them with a single terminal command?

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: With Kubuntu I think it is, it restores the last session and opens all windows previously used.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

```bsh
for i in google-chrome nautilus gnome-terminal gedit ; do
    setsid "$i" >  /dev/null 2>&1 
done
```

`setsid` or `nohup` can be used to daemonize a process, with `setsid` being preferred because it starts each process as new session leader, effectively disconnecting it from terminal.  See also, [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/85039).

As for `> /dev/null 2>&1` that just sends both normal and error streams from each program into `/dev/null` so that you can still use terminal normally. See also [What does & mean exactly in output redirection?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031663/295286) and [What is the differences between &> and 2>&1](https://askubuntu.com/q/635065/295286)

I don't remember command for system monitor off the top of my head, so I'll leave that up to you.

Feel free to turn this loop into either a function that can live in your `~/.bashrc` or make a full-blown scripts. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to make a bash script with all the needed commands to start those programs.

You could even put that script in Startup Applications so it gets run on every bootup.

Comment: Not gonna work, unless you start each in background. Each command blocks script execution until it exists. Only then next one runs.  So launch it in background with appending `&` to the end.

Comment: I tested it using using firefox and mate-terminal with no problems. I am assuming your "exists" should be exits.

Comment: Yes. Typing on phone is prone to typos. And how did you structure the script ?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 16.04 LTS

mate-terminal
firefox

Comment: The mate-terminal has `#` in front, which tells me it's commented out. Your script only runs `firefox`.  What should be done is `firefox &`. Then on next line `mate-terminal &`. And so on and so forth.

Comment: No command is commented out. Only comment is for Ubuntu version. Mate-terminal and firefox are on separate lines. There are often multiple ways of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Alright. Apparently `mate-terminal` launches itself in background. In general however thia shouldn't happen. As I said, scripts are sequential, and each program blocks execution.

Answer (score 1):

To open all of the above applications at one, you could execute something like this:

`chromium ; nautilus ; gnome-terminal ; gnome-system-monitor ; gedit`

To make this startup every time you Log In, you could put this command into a [.desktop file](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/) on the `Exec=` line.

Place this file into `/usr/share/applications` and open `gnome-session-properties`. Simply add your new application to the current list of startup applications. This should do the trick.