# Command to append rows(lines) to a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm new at scripting, and i need help with this:

I have a "table.txt" file that has this:

```
00          02          03          04         05          06          07
```

and i need to append lines in this file,  corresponding to each column.

Example:

```
A = 10
B = 20
result00 = A+B
```

In table...:

```
00           02         03          04          05          06          07
${result00}
```

and i need to do it with all 7 columns. Each column has a different value, from a different variable.

The final file, need to have 400 lines.

I need a table like that:

```
00           02         03          04          05          06          07
15           20         53          100         430         100         12
[...]        [...]      [...]       [...]       [...]       [...]       [...]
403          212        21          43          50          202         10
```

Comment: Where do the variables come from?

Comment: @Zanna before it, i need to count lines of a bunch of files in a directory, and the number of lines is the result that i need to append in this text table. Each position in the table need to have a result of a number of lines in a unique file. I need only to know how to append this result.

Comment: So are you just asking for a [Command to append line to a text file without opening an editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21555/command-to-append-line-to-a-text-file-without-opening-an-editor) ?