# chpasswd -e not seting password correctly

Tags: password

I'm trying to set my password with `echo "user:SOME_PASSWORD_STRING" | sudo chpasswd -e` but when I do this, my password is not set to the correct password.  The passwords I'm using are one's I've copied from `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: Wait… you have password hashes stored in `/etc/passwd`? Aren't we supposed to store those in `/etc/shadow` which is inaccessible to regular users for security reasons? I really hope you're not operating any publicly accessible servers.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Oops.  I meant `/etc/shadow`.  Fixed

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of double quotes in the echo statement.  The password had several `$` characters in it, which was translated as bash variables.

The correct command uses single quotes:

```
echo 'user:SOME_PASSWORD_STRING' | sudo chpasswd -e
```

See here for more on quotes: [Differences between doublequotes " ", singlequotes ' ' and backticks ´ ´ on commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20034/differences-between-doublequotes-singlequotes-and-backticks-%C2%B4-%C2%B4-on-comm)

Comment: U saved me man !!