# if command syntax

Tags: command-line, bash, syntax

My code of shell script is as follows:

```
echo "Enter file name";
read fname;
if [-f$fname];
then
    echo "File already exists";
fi`
```

However, when I run my script, I get this error:

```
[-ffile]: not found
```

I have tried spacing `-f $fname` but I still get the same error.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: `if [ -f $fname ];` is spaces are missing?

Comment: See [Differences between doublequotes “ ”, singlequotes ' ' and backticks ´ ´ on commandline?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20034/differences-between-doublequotes-singlequotes-and-backticks-%c2%b4-%c2%b4-on-comm) for detailed background regarding quoting in shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have added a value that contains a space. To prevent this, always quote your variables:

```
if [ -f "$fname" ]
```

Also, note that `[` and `]` need a space around. Why? Because `[` is a command, so it must be separated by a white space from the preceding statement. You can read about it by typing `man test`.

All together:

```
echo "Enter file name";
read -r fname;
if [ -f "$fname" ]; then
   echo "File already exists";
fi
```

---

See a test on how quotes matter:

```
$ touch "a b"
$ filename="a b"
$ [ -f $filename ] && echo "exists!"
bash: [: a: binary operator expected
$ [ -f "$filename" ] && echo "exists!"
exists!
```

Answer (score 4):

I would expect `-e "$fname"` or `if [[ -e $fname ]]` (the last one is not universal across shells).

So

```
echo "Enter file name"; read fname; if [ -e "$fname" ]; then echo "File already exists"; fi
```

In any case and to make sure: always use quotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the script should look like

```
echo "Enter file name";
read fname;
if [ -f "$fname" ];
then 
  echo "File already exists";
fi
```

You need space around the brackets and should quote the variable.