# First Bash Script Problem

Tags: bash, scripts, git

I'm completely new to Bash, and I'm trying to make a simple script to automate Git pulling and pushing from a repo, but I can't get it to work.

Here is a pastebin of the code: http://pastebin.com/JrXqktD4

```
#!/bin/bash
#Git Puller / Pusher for MobArenaBattles

echo "Please type whether you want to pull or push:"

read proc
cd $HOME/Desktop/IdeaProjects/Plugins/MobArenaBattles

if ["$proc"="push"]; then
  echo "Please type the commit message:"
  read message
  git status
  git add -A
  git commit -m $message
  git push
elif ["$proc"="pull"]; then
  git status
  git pull
else
  echo "Invalid choice! Exiting."
fi
```

The error I get is:

```
./MAB Git.sh: line 9: [push=push]: command not found
./MAB Git.sh: line 16: [push=pull]: command not found
```

I have tried using `==` and `-eq` but it comes up with the same error. Sorry if I'm being stupid, it's my first attempt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [if command syntax](http://askubuntu.com/questions/687232/if-command-syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need spaces:

```
if [ "$s1" == "$s2" ]
```

Comment: The answer is correct, I just want to emphasize that there must be spaces around the square brackets `[`/`]` as well as around the comparison operator `==`. Also you may use both `=` or `==` as they are equal in Bash, but `-eq` is only for comparing numerical values, not for strings.