# Send mail with subject as string variable

Tags: 14.04

Ubuntu noob here, I want to send an email where I get subject from variable inside sh script, in script below notice subject variable. Mail is sent but the subject is "$subject" instead of SSH login

```
#!/bin/bash
##This script sends a message

    subject="SSH Login:"
    curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/adoptatias.com/messages -F from='Excited User <postmaster@mydomain.com>' -F to='mymail@gmail.com' -F subject='$subject' -F text='Detected succesfull SSH login'


exit 0;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Single quotes prevent variable expansion - see for example https://askubuntu.com/a/20041/178692

Comment: You've tagged your release as 14.04?  Are you sure you're using the 2014-April release, and it's EOSS (*end of standard support*) thus off-topic here, and only gets security updates/fixes if ESM is applied?